# Google Maps Android API v2 - for ARM only?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-2, android-x86

[Google Maps Android API v2](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/)

I'm getting error while trying to install sucessfully compiled maps demo app (`%android-sdk%\extras\google\google_play_services\samples\maps\`) on **android-x86** device (Intel Mint):

> Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_CPU_ABI_INCOMPATIBLE]

The same APK can be installed on **ARM** devices and works successfully.

Comment: are you sure you are building for android-x86 as well?

Comment: no, just using default demo project settings. since there is no "libs" folders anywhere i am confused that it is targeted any specific platform

Comment: created [issue](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4686)

Comment: also, there is another requirement: min Google Play service version. `WARN/GooglePlayServicesUtil: Google Play services out of date. Requires 2010100 but found 1013`. And NullPointer is thrown in mapFragment.getMap()

Comment: This issue happens to me only when using Intellij Idea. You have to build your APK and install it manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. It is an official Google app and does not come in source code form to be recompiled for x86/MIPS.

Use the Genymotion Android emulator, see this other question: [How do you install Google frameworks (Play, Accounts, etc.) on a Genymotion virtual device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17831990/how-do-you-install-google-frameworks-play-accounts-etc-on-a-genymotion-virtu)

Comment: At this time there are not only ARM devices on the market, but x86 too. Intel is not sleeping too) I believe it is/will be recompiled for another platforms too