# How do you install Google frameworks (Play, Accounts, etc.) on a Genymotion virtual device?

Tags: android, google-play-services, android-virtual-device, genymotion

I'm currently trying out Genymotion and boy, it's so much faster than the ADT emulator.

But I need to install Google Play to download some apps into it. How do I do this?

Comment: See the official Genymotion FAQ: https://www.genymotion.com/help/desktop/faq/#google-play-services

Comment: use this method, it is working for me

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17831990/how-do-you-install-google-frameworks-play-accounts-etc-on-a-genymotion-virt/40423406#40423406

Answer (score 573, accepted):

## Update May 28th, 2017: This method is no longer supported by me and doesn't work anymore as far as I know. Don't try it.

---

<strike># How To Add Google Apps and ARM Support to Genymotion v2.0+ #</strike>

Original Source: [[GUIDE] Genymotion | Installing ARM Translation and GApps - XDA-Developers](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2528952)

---

**Note(Feb 2nd):** Contrary to previous reports, it's been discovered that Android 4.4 does in fact work with ARM translation, although it is buggy. Follow the steps the same as before, just make sure you download the 4.4 GApps.

**UPDATE-v1.1:** I've gotten more up-to-date builds of libhoudini and have updated the ZIP file. This fixes a lot of app crashes and hangs. Just flash the new one, and it should work.

---

This guide is for getting back both ARM translation/support (this is what causes the "INSTALL_FAILED_CPU_ABI_INCOMPATIBLE" errors) and Google Play apps in your Genymotion VM.

1. Download the following ZIPs:

   - **[ARM Translation Installer v1.1](http://filetrip.net/dl?4SUOrdcMRv)** ([Mirrors](http://www.mirrorcreator.com/files/0ZIO8PME/Genymotion-ARM-Translation_v1.1.zip_links))
     ***If you have issues flashing ARM translation, try re-downloading from a mirror***
   - Download the correct GApps for your Android version:
     ***If you have issues flashing GApps, try re-downloading from a mirror***

     - [Google Apps for Android 6.0](https://www.androidfilehost.com/?fid=24052804347835438)
     - [Google Apps for Android 5.1](http://downloadandroidrom.com/file/gapps/5.1/gapps-L-4-21-15.zip)
     - [Google Apps for Android 5.0](https://www.androidfilehost.com/?fid=95784891001614559)
     - [Google Apps for Android 4.4](http://www.androidfilehost.com/?fid=23311191640114013) ([Download from CM11 Links](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Google_Apps#gappsCM11)) *(4.4 GApps might have bugs)*
     - [Google Apps for Android 4.3](https://www.androidfilehost.com/?fid=23060877490000124) ([Mirrors](http://www.mirrorcreator.com/files/AJ8OITDD/gapps-jb-20130813-signed_0.zip_links))
     - [Google Apps for Android 4.2](https://www.androidfilehost.com/?fid=23060877490000128)
     - [Google Apps for Android 4.1](https://www.androidfilehost.com/?fid=22979706399755082)
2. Next open your Genymotion VM and go to the home screen
3. Now drag&drop the **Genymotion-ARM-Translation_v1.1.zip** onto the Genymotion VM window.
4. It should say "File transfer in progress". Once it asks you to flash it, click 'OK'.
5. Now reboot your VM using ADB (`adb reboot`) or an app like ROM Toolbox. If nescessary you can simply close the VM window, but I don't recommend it.
6. Once you're on the home screen again drag&drop the **gapps-*-signed.zip** (the name varies) onto your VM, and click 'OK' when asked.
7. Once it finishes, again reboot your VM and open the Google Play Store.
8. Sign in using your Google account
9. Once in the Store go to the 'My Apps' menu and let everything update (it fixes a lot of issues). Also try updating [Google Play Services](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.gms) directly.
10. Now try searching for 'Netflix' and 'Google Drive'
11. If both apps show up in the results and you're able to Download/Install them, then congratulations: you now have ARM support and Google Play fully set up!

I've tested this on Genymotion v2.0.1-v2.1 using Android 4.3 and 4.4 images. Feel free to skip the GApps steps if you only want the ARM support. It'll work perfectly fine by itself.

---

***Old Zips:*** [v1.0](http://d01.megashares.com/index.php?d01=ML6UeXl). Don't download these as they will not solve your issues. It is left for archival and experimental purposes.

Comment: It didn't work for me. The Genymotion-ARM-Translation.zip flashes correctly but the gapps zip does not, it behaves as before. I had Genymotion 2.0.0 but I have upgraded it to 2.0.1 and it behaves the same way. I have deleted the old .ova files and forced it to re-download them, but nothing changes. One question... What version number do you see when you deploy a new 4.3 image (in the "Virtual device deployment dialog", in the "System version" section)? I always see 2.0.0 and I don't know if that might be the problem...

Comment: @AlejandroMezcua Which 4.3 image are you trying? I've been using the Nexus 7 4.3 1280x800. If you can make a new device and then record a logcat while you try to flash GApps, post it to pastebin so I can see.

Comment: Worked for me! Used the Galaxy Nexus - 4.3 - API 18 - 720x1280 Image

Comment: @jmeier Try my updated ZIP, should work even better

Comment: please add what has changed as well to your updated answer...

Comment: @jmeier I did, I replaced the libhoudini(the ARM Translator) with newer versions that run better, and are far more stable.

Comment: The new versions work correctly! I was trying with both a Nexus emulator and a Galaxy S4. I have downloaded the specific files in the message and it works now. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I can't drag and drop the file, someone have the same issue?

Comment: I tried to add gapps to the preview build of Android 2.3.7 (Nexus S). Installed ARM Translation, then gapps for GingerBread. All seems to work fine, but when I try to login to my Google account, it says the username and password don't match. Tried many times and I'm sure they are correct, can login elsewhere with same and there is no problem. Hmm. Did Google try to block us from using gapps in emulators in this way, by rejecting login now?

Comment: OK, I see the problem. My account is set for extra auth by SMS codes, and probably the old version of gapps does not know how to ask for auth code. I was able to log in fine on GingerBread emulator with another account without this extra security step.

Comment: After following the steps above, I'm not able to open Genymotion device.

Comment: @Hardik What exactly happens when you try to open the device?

Comment: @japzone It's an incomplete download problem, the connection on the website is disconnected after some time, I've found in various forums that it's most common problem with other users too. If possible mention this problem below the link you've given.Btw, thanks for asking.

Comment: @Hardik Oh yeah, I've been tackling that problem. Will probably make some mirrors for the GApps since Goo.IM seems to be having issues for some reason. Thanks for reminding me.

Comment: @japzone I have tried this multiple times on Android 4.3, 4.2 and 4.1 and with different devices. I am able to flash, but not GApps. I got the error message 'Ooops, something went wrong while flashing gapps-jb-20130813-signed.zip' each time I try.

Comment: @brendan Yeah, sounds like a corrupted download. I don't know what's been wrong with downloads from Goo.im but it seems that a lot of people have been getting corrupted downloads from there. It's not as convenient as Goo.im but I've made some mirrors for Android 4.3 GApps. I'll get around to making mirrors for the other Android versions later. Let me know if you still have problems. http://goo.gl/cC8xHR

Comment: @japzone Update: I continued with the rest of your instructions and I was able to see Netflix and Google Drive and also get maps v2 working within an app that I built.

Comment: The newly released 4.4.2 VMs do not work with the currently-available ARM translation (1.1). If you don't mind a few FCs, the various 4.4 Gapps packages seem to work. I used http://goo.im/devs/paranoidandroid/roms/gapps/pa_gapps-stock-4.4.2-20140123-signed.zip

Comment: @Pierre-LucPaour Yeah, I thought that might happen. 4.4 is very different from 4.3 under the hood, and I suspected the Libhoudini wouldn't work. I'll have to look into it, but for now I don't see a way of getting it to work, unless it's something really simple(like some config file has to have something changed) there's not much I can do since I don't have any source code for libhoudini because it's closed source software by Intel.

Comment: @Pierre-LucPaour I just tested ARM Translation and GApps on 4.4.2 images, and it worked fine. But GApps is a bit buggy like you said.

Comment: To expand on rebooting the VM (step 5) - this can be done reliably through the UI as follows: (1) hold down the power button and select "Power Off" when prompted.  (2) Once the VM's UI freezes (the power-down spinner will stop spinning), close the VM window.  (3) Restart the VM from the Genymotion control panel.

Comment: @RichZwaap Yes that is another neat way to do it, but I've actually found after testing that simply closing the Genymotion window gives a graceful enough shutdown by itself. No problems have occured from doing so, and monitoring the Virtualbox VM shows that it takes it's time to shutdown by itself. I think GM gives the shutdown command automatically when you close the window.

Comment: On Windows 8.1 I'm unable to upload zip file - get an error saying 'is a directory'. Any known solution?

Comment: Update - this was for Xperia Z sim, Nexus 7 installed fine, but can't download GMS from GooglePlay - error 403

Comment: Which ZIP, GApps, ARM Translation? What version of Android, 4.3, 4.4? And what do you mean by GMS, Google Play Services?

Comment: I used the 4.4 version and the google apps zip file didn't try to flash after copying it. I tried a lot of other files and none worked until I went to http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Google_Apps and downloaded the top one by torrent. It worked! Thanks so much.

Comment: @ColinKeenan It seems that the zips are very fragile or Genymotion is very sensitive. Most of the problems people report with them I can only narrow to some kind of download corruption. Usually downloading from a mirror works. Using the torrent was a good idea, since Torrent programs have built in file verification(if a piece is bad it just requests it again). I'll look into adding torrent mirror links soon, some people will probably prefer them anyway.

Comment: works for Nexus 4 - Android 4.3, not working for Nexus 5 - Andorid 4.4

Comment: @SophiaF At what point is it not working?

Comment: Works with S2 JB4.1 image, yay!

Comment: I've been able to install both .zip files (using the Cyanogen mirrors for Gapps) on GenyMotion N5 4.4.2, but Google Play Services keeps crashing every few seconds. GMail is working but not Google Play.

Comment: @KevinGaudin Yeah, I've been running into that too but haven't been able to track down the problem. Sometimes it goes away, sometimes it doesn't. Just try to update all of your Google Apps, or leave the VM running a while so Play Services can update itself. Hopefully that helps.

Comment: @Japzone  .... I used the first zip(transalator) that is a translator .... succussfully .....  but second image when i tried to add ..... i get the error as device got corrupted and closes....then i am not able to load the emulator also ... any Ideas ? .... Is zip corropted ... can you point me to proper zip ? .... any inputs would be helpful ... Note i tried with 18(4.3)

Comment: @CasperSky I'm sorry I can't understand your issue since it seems part of you post is missing. If more space is needed, post your question using Pastebin and put the link here.

Comment: I have a android v4.3 phone and want to install google app. I have downloaded your Google Apps for Android 4.3. How can I install it? there is no apk file.

Comment: @5YrsLaterDBA You drag&drop the ARM Translation and GApps ZIP files onto the Genymotion Virtual Machine window. Read the Directions above.

Comment: @japzone I am try to install GAPP on a REAL android phone.The same procedure?

Comment: @5YrsLaterDBA This isn't the place to ask about that. You'll need to Root your Phone and flash a custom recovery, like TWRP, in order to install the GApps zip on an Android device. Go to a site like XDA-Developers and research how to Root your specific device.

Comment: @japzone yes, I rooted my phone already. I installed the gapp in my previous phone (with android 4.0) 3 yrs ago and cannot remember the exact steps but what I can remember is just copy the gapp to somewhere without any third party tools, like TWRP, to install it.

Comment: @5YrsLaterDBA This is not the place to ask that. Comments are only to ask or comment on the specific Question/Answer, not to ask off topic questions. No offense, but you need to ask somewhere else.

Comment: @japzone when i drag n drop the zipped files vm emulator says "Invalid filename: /.file/id/6571367.605xxxx". The last four digits in error message changes with file I drag n drop. Any idea??

Comment: It worked for me! (Genymotion v2.2.2, Android Nexus 5 4.4.2). Google Play Services was crashing, but it fixed after I updated it on Play Store! Thanks.

Comment: @BrunoLemos I am facing problems in (Genymotion v2.2.2, Google Nexus 5 4.4.2) API 19, Every time I launch it, shows alert saying `"Unfortunately, Setup wizard has stopped."` Since I added GAPPS file to it. Can you please help me sort it out. Thanks

Comment: @Dhruv Try a complete reinstall (delete all genymotion files and the vm at Virtual Box). Reinstall the ARM, and make sure to install the right version of gapps (I downloaded the "kk" version from the official website: https://goo.im/gapps/).

Comment: When my drag&drop stopped working, I installed it via ADB as seen in this blog post: http://blog.tomaslinhart.com/how-to-install-google-apps-in-genymotion/

Comment: @BrunoLemos Thanks a lot for the info and details,I'll check as per suggested.

Comment: @japzone Thanks. Files added successfully and I was able to install and use Google Drive. Installing games was also successful. However, when I try to launch any game, like(Clash of Clans, X-Fighting, Castle Clash and Candy Crush), it force closes [Unfortunately, *game* has stopped.]. Any idea how to go on with this?

Comment: This worked good for Genymotion 2.3.0 using an Android 4.1.1 image just now. Was able to run Google Play and download apps after.

Comment: This no longer works for the new version of genymotion, could you post update for that

Comment: Google Play services for 5.0 (Lollipop) can be found here: https://gist.github.com/wbroek/9321145 (Versions 4.4.4, 4.3, 4.2, 4.1, 2.3.7 are also available)

Comment: Working with Genymotion version 2.3.1 and Android 5.0.0 tablet

Comment: goo.im links don't work anymore

Comment: GAPPS not working for 5.1. stuck in boot loop

Comment: UPDATE: after 5-6 reboots it Works. My emulator is N5 running 5.1 . Cool !

Comment: i am using genymotion 2.5 after after dragging dropping both files and rebooting each time nothing happens !

Comment: This guide is for getting back both ARM translation/support (this is what causes the "INSTALL_FAILED_CPU_ABI_INCOMPATIBLE" errors)

I guess that's because you used ARM version of Google apps? Why not downloading zip with x86 apps (from opengapps.org for example) and flashing that? No need for ARM then and they would work faster anyway...

Comment: it seems to be working but it always pops up the error "unfortunately the process gapps has stopped" (4.4 KK)

Comment: didn't work for me. Google services keep on crashing with a dialog saying "Unfortunately, Google Play services has stopped."

Comment: It gets stock in "**Archive flashing in progress.**". What can I do?

Comment: Where can I find the GApps for Android 7.0? I tried using the one for Android 6.0 and I get the error "Google Play services keeps stopping" when I try to open any Google app.

Comment: 7.0 is here: http://opengapps.org/

Comment: use this method, it is working for me

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17831990/how-do-you-install-google-frameworks-play-accounts-etc-on-a-genymotion-virt/40423406#40423406

Answer (score 40):

**Install Genymotion 2.10 or above, now there is a dedicated button to install Google Play Services name "Open GApps".** [Link for more info](https://www.genymotion.com/blog/2-10-open-gapps-widget/)

### 3 Steps process for Genymotion 2.9 or below:-

[4.4 Kitkat](http://opengapps.org/?download=true&arch=x86&api=4.4&variant=pico)
[5.0 Lollipop](http://opengapps.org/?download=true&arch=x86&api=5.0&variant=pico)
[5.1 Lollipop](http://opengapps.org/?download=true&arch=x86&api=5.1&variant=pico)
[6.0 Marshmallow](http://opengapps.org/?download=true&arch=x86&api=6.0&variant=pico)
[7.0 Nougat](http://opengapps.org/?download=true&arch=x86&api=7.0&variant=pico)
[7.1 Nougat (webview patch)](http://opengapps.org/?download=true&arch=x86&api=7.1&variant=pico)
[8.0 Oreo](http://opengapps.org/?download=true&arch=x86&api=8.0&variant=pico)
[8.1 Oreo](http://opengapps.org/?download=true&arch=x86&api=8.1&variant=pico)
[9.0 Pie](https://opengapps.org/?download=true&arch=x86&api=9.0&variant=pico)

1. Download from above link
2. Just drag & drop downloaded zip file to genymotion and restart
3. Add google account and download "Google Play Music" and Run.

Comment: The main answer no longer works. This one works as expected, and it's simple enough to be the new valid answer.

Comment: Genymotion has now a dedicated button for this in the top right

Comment: @Mc128k added that info in answer with link, thanks a lot

Answer (score 29):

**EDIT 2**

After three months we can say: no more official Google Apps in Genymotion and [CyanogenMod](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CyanogenMod)-like method is only way to get Google Apps. However, you can still use the previous project of the Genymotion team: [AndroVM](http://androvm.org/blog/download/) ([download mirror](http://mirror1.jarfil.net/androvm.org/Download/)).

---

**EDIT**

Google apps will be removed from Genymotion in November. You can find more information on the [Genymotion Google Plus](https://plus.google.com/111561249038747241670/posts/jNF8Kwu5p1c) page.

---

Choose virtual device with Google Apps:

[image]

Done:

[image]

Comment: Google Apps devices are deprecated in Genymotion now.

Comment: I tried AndroVM (mentioned in your Edit 3), and double clicked androVM_vbox86tp_4.1.1_r4-20121106-gapps-houdini.ova   Error I got was Failed to create the VirtualBox COM object.
The application will now terminate
Callee RC: 
CO_E_SERVER_EXEC_FAILURE (0x80080005)

Comment: I am not getting Genymotion Cloud option, is it available for personal use version?

Comment: With the latest Genymotion, there is a button right there to get Google Apps I believe. at least that is how I got to use Google Maps on it

Answer (score 11):

Now there is **official FAQ** for using Google Play in [How do I install Google Play Services?](https://www.genymotion.com/help/desktop/faq/#google-play-services), here the FAQ text:

> For intellectual property reasons, Google Play Services are not
>   included by default in Genymotion virtual devices. However, if you
>   really need them, you can use the packages provided by OpenGapps.
>   Simply follow these steps:
>
> 1. Visit [opengapps.org](http://opengapps.org/)
> 2. Select x86 as platform
> 3. Choose the Android version corresponding to your virtual device
> 4. Select nano as variant
> 5. Download the zip file
> 6. Drag & Drop the zip installer in new Genymotion virtual device (2.7.2 and above only)
> 7. Follow the pop-up instructions
>
> > Please note Genymobile Inc. and Genymotion assume no liability
> >     whatsoever resulting from the download, install and use of Google Play
> >     Services within your virtual devices. You are solely responsible for
> >     the use and assume all liability related thereto. Moreover, we
> >     disclaim any warranties of any kind for a particular purpose regarding
> >     the compatibility of the OpenGapps packages with any version of
> >     Genymotion.

Comment: please mark this answer as accepted. This solution worked for me

Comment: works for me, thank you very much!

Answer (score 8):

#### Alright, this is probably the easiest way to do it:

1. First of all, you will have to install [GAPPS](http://wiki.rootzwiki.com/Google_Apps#Universal_Packages_2).
2. Next, open the virtual box and wait for the home screen to show up on Genymotion.
3. Drag and drop the GAPPS folder that you had downloaded earlier on into Genymotion.
4. You would get a prompt. Click OK. You would see a lot of errors, but just ignore them and wait for the successful prompt to come up. Click OK again and restart the virtual device.
5. A Google account screen should show up. Open up the playstore app if it doesn't show up. Sign into your account. Again ignore the errors.
6. The playstore should open now and should be fully functional.

Answer (score 5):

I could flash the ARM translation but not the gapps, using https://stackoverflow.com/a/20013322/98057. I got the 'Ooops, something went wrong while flashing gapps-jb-20121011-signed.zip' error mentioned above. If you read the Genymotion logs and find an entry like:

```
Sep 16 23:00:02 [Genymotion Player] [Error] [Adb][shell] Unable to finished process:  "Process operation timed out"
```

Try to apply the flash using `adb`directly:

```
$ adb -s 192.168.56.101:5555 shell "/system/bin/check-archive.sh /sdcard/Download/gapps-jb-20121011-signed.zip"
$ adb -s 192.168.56.101:5555 shell "/system/bin/flash-archive.sh /sdcard/Download/gapps-jb-20121011-signed.zip"
$ adb reboot
```

Change these commands according to what your log files say (the path and IP will probably be different).

I found the Genymobile log files in the following folder, by the way:

```
~/.Genymobile/Genymotion/deployed/<device name>/genymotion-player.log
```

Comment: Download Gapps from this site http://opengapps.org/

Answer (score 4):

Try to do all the steps specified in the link below and before that upgrade [VirtualBox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VirtualBox) to 4.2 by following the instructions in *[VirtualBox 4.2.0 Released With Support For Drag'n'drop From Host To Linux Guests, More](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/09/virtualbox-420-released-with-support.html)*. Then upgrade Genymotion to the latest version.

Go to the desktop and run Genymotion. Select a virtual device with Android version 4.2 and then drag and drop the two files **Genymotion-ARM-Translation_v1.1.zip** first. Then Genymotion will show progress and after this it will promt a dialog. Then click OK and it will ask to reboot the device. Restart [ADB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_Debug_Bridge). Do the same steps for the second file, **gapps-jb-20130812-signed.zip** and restart ADB.

I hope this will resolve the issue. Check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20121883/how-to-install-google-play-service-in-the-genymotion-ubuntu-13-04-currently-i/20137324#20137324) - it explains it clearer.

Comment: You're reposting an answer, from another question, that reposted an answer from the question you're posting to. Why?

Answer (score 4):

**Google Apps KitKat for Genymotion.**

Download the Google Apps ZIP file from the link which contain the essential Google Apps such as Play Store, [Gmail](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gmail), [YouTube](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YouTube), etc.

https://www.mediafire.com/?qbbt4lhyu9q10ix

After finishing booting, drag and drop the ZIP file we downloaded named **update-gapps-4-4-2-signed.zip** to the Genymotion Window. It starts installing the Google Apps, and it asks for your confirmation. Confirm it.

Comment: I'd recommend that link for downloading gapps http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Google_Apps#Downloads

Answer (score 1):

If anyone got an error while signing in to Google and this message appear:

> Couldn't Sign In 
>   can't establish a reliable connection to the server...

then try to sign in from the browser - in YouTube, Gmail, Google sites, etc.

This helped me. After signing in in the browser I was able to sign in the Google Play app...

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes "ARM Translation Installer v1.1" is not working.. Here is the simple solution to install Google Play.

1. Go to this link: http://www.mediafire.com/download/jdn83v1v3bregyu/Galaxy+S4++HTC+One++Xperia+Z+-+4.2.2+-+with+Google+Apps+-+API+17+-+1080x1920.zip
2. Download the file from the link and extract to get the Android virtual device with Google Play store. The file will be in the name as “Galaxy S4 HTC One Xperia Z – 4.2.2 – with Google Apps – API 17 – 1080×1920″.
3. Close all your Genymotion store running in the background.
4. Copy that extracted file in to the following folder.
   C:\Users\'username'\AppData\Local\Genymobile\Genymotion\deployed
5. After you copy you should see this path:
   C:\Users\'username'\AppData\Local\Genymobile\Genymotion\deployed\Galaxy S4 HTC One Xperia Z - 4.2.2 - with Google Apps - API 17 - 1080x1920
6. Inside the “Galaxy S4 HTC One Xperia Z – 4.2.2 – with Google Apps – API 17 – 1080×1920″ folder you will see many *.vmdk and *.vbox files.
7. Now open [VirtualBox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VirtualBox) and select Machine->Add and browse for the above folder and import the *.vbox file.
8. Restart Genymotion. Done.