# "This app won't run unless you update google play services" alert

Tags: android, android-emulator, google-play-services

I am getting "Update Google Play Services" alert when running project on emulator. If I click `OK` then there is one more alert behind it. I keep clicking `OK` and there are tons of alerts already popped up and I end up giving up.

Message looks as below :

[image]

I've tried updating everything in SDK manager. Also tried in Eclipse, Help->Check for updates.

Comment: If you are using Maps API v2, emulator won't be able to load maps. You'll have to test it in the device. But if you want to do it in Emulator, there are workarounds available. Maps API v2 requires Google Play Services to run, which aren't there in Emulator.

Comment: @Dhaval I know that. But any other screen should be fine.

Comment: Is is running in device or just Emulator problem? So we can narrow down the problem

Comment: @Dhaval On device this runs fine. Problem with emulator only.

Comment: Ok. Then it must be the problem with Maps API v2. I searched myself as well, the problem seems to be the same as i said before. This is a very unique problem. Maybe try Launching application with activity other than MapActivity.

Comment: @Dhaval I am not launching mapActivity. This is another activity only. And I it was working fine till now even though I have integrated google maps a long time ago.

Comment: Ok. I'll get back if i can find something. But do let us know, if you solve it before. It will help all of us.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39196/discussion-between-akash-and-dhaval)

Comment: Hi All, I am facing this issue in devices where maps were designed based upon API v2 my mobile version is Android 4.4.3 (Kit kat). Thanks in advance

Comment: This question has been answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40084060/6482813)

Answer (score 11):

**Updated: Jun 27 2019:**

The new [google x86 emulator](https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2017/04/google-play-system-images-android.html) with play services is exactly like a device where you can install apps from play store and all other things.

**Previous Answer:**

I faced similar problem while trying google maps in emulator. While some people have been able to run google play services in their emulator by downloading google play services application from their mobile, making the apk file and then installing that file in emulator, it is really complicated process and works for certain api level only. Same is the case with emulator using  google api's that shift with builtin maps and google play services. The maps application will work in emulator while your application asks for update to google play services. So the wise thing to do is to test it in real hardware.

Answer (score 10):

For me, I had to go to `settings | apps` on my emulator and then find `Google Play Services`, I then saw that the version number was no where near the current version number (6.7.74 as against the current 7.3.0)

I then went to my dependencies and changed:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.3.0'
```

to

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.+'
```

You'll get warnings saying a newer version is available and to avoid using + in version numbers but if you've spent the entire day looking for a solution like I did, you could care less.

Comment: I was having exactly same situation. But eventually it worked for me. Thank you. :-)

Answer (score 6):

In android studio changing the depencies work for me:

`com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.+`

to:

`com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.0.+`

Comment: it worked with me too (I was trying it on LG G2 Mobile), but why?

Comment: yeah, same here. I was using 5.2.08 and changing to 5.0.+ worked fine.

Answer (score 4):

Now you can also use your emulator to run Android MAP API V2.

**Note: Only Android 4.2.2 and higher versions of the Google APIs platform include Google Play services.**

The problem here is that **you have an older version of *Google Play Services***. Update to the latest version by opening the **SDK Manager** => **Extras** => **Google Play Services.**

Comment: Eclipse:  After updating with the SDK Manager.  Create a new google play library project to replace your existing google play library project.

Comment: Did you create a new google play library project and add to your project properties as library. Also you need to place the google-play-services.jar in project libs folder.

Comment: @ArshadParwez Yes, I created. I already had old .jar in libs. So just importing a new google play library should set .jar.

Answer (score 3):

you can try using new `Genymotion Android emulator` in which you can update google play services. I have faced this alert and able to update it.

It seems like we can't test latest Google maps API, which is dependant on google play store app which is missing in `Google's Android Emulator`.

`Genymotion Android Emulator` comes with Google Play store app.

NOTE: Genymotion v2.0 discontinued packaging virtual machine with google apps , but refer this [**link**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20013322/877994) to add Google Apps Manually to Genymotion

Comment: Since Genymotion 2.0.0 released in November 2013, they have stopped giving emulator bundled with Google apps. [Read more](http://www.technotalkative.com/lazy-productive-android-developer-2/)

Comment: There is still a way , refer : Adding Google Apps to Genymotion http://stackoverflow.com/a/20013322/877994

Comment: Yeah they have stopped giving OFFICIALLY. Otherwise Everything is possible in Software and Programming Industry :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.
It's nice that in the newer emulators (for version 17 and up) come with the play services included, but what about older versions?

eventually i found the emulators provided by `testobject`. all their emulators (starting at version 15) come with the updated play services and google APIs (maps v2 etc'), for both ARM and x86.

Answer (score 0):

Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/19734573/3284964. It helped me. For me it works on 4.3 emulator (google play services release 3.2.65) and google play services for froyo lib in my app.

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem with Android Studio when it imported my Eclipse project.

Look for Google Play Services in your build.gradle.

`dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
}`

Change this to use an exact version:

`dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.0+'
}`

Then clean build (Build -> Clean Project).

Answer (score 0):

Just did some checking and I realise this question is quite old but, it seems API19 Google Apis Disk Image works with Google Play Services just tested it with an application im working on and it shows the Goolge Maps V2 just fine.

Answer (score 0):

(Only for Android Studio Users)

I have faced the same problem and solved it by updating Android Studio and SDK libraries.