# “App won't run unless you update Google Play services” with Google Maps API

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I created an app with Google Maps API. After few hours of trying to resolve errors, I successfuly runned it(without crashes). But now I get a error.

[image]

That alert means “App won't run unless you update Google Play services”.
I heard about that error with emulator, but I'm using real device(LG P350 on Gingerbread).
I have got device with android 2.3 so I use SupportLibrary.

My activity file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".Map" >

     <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And AndroidManifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="io.secrop.where360"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />



        <permission
            android:name="io.secorp.where360.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
            android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="io.secorp.where360.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>    
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
        <!-- The following two permissions are not required to use
         Google Maps Android API v2, but are recommended. -->
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="MY_API_KEY"/>

    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />


        <activity
            android:name="io.secrop.where360.Map"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


    </application>

</manifest>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: have you updated google play services?

Comment: Check in your Android SDK Manager that you have the latest version.

Comment: When you create avd you need to select google api for ex if you create avd for api18 you need to select google api 18. But first it must be downloaded

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have hit a wrong point in time.

Google Play Services have been updated to 4.0.30 very recently and so you seem to be using that version of google-play-services_lib. Assumption based on this line:

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

Not all devices have received an update of GooglePlayServices.APK, which needs to be at least the same version as a client library you are using.

Check version of GPServices.APK in Settings app. For me it is still at 3.2.66 and last time I had to wait few days for the update.

If you are using gradle, you can put lower version dependency. If not, you have to download older version of google-play-services_lib from somewhere.

**Edit:**

or get Google Play Services for Froyo from Android SDK. It is the same as previous release (3.2.65).

Comment: Thank you. I downloaded Google Play Services 4.0.30 from another source and it works well!

Comment: how do i put the lower version dependency in my gradle? Please tell me. Thank you.

Comment: @RadityaKurnianto should be something like `compile '...:3.2.+'`

Comment: @MaciejGórski as google play services version on sdk is 5.2.+ I've put the major version to compile `5.0.+`. Thank you for your answer.