# Google play services update error

Tags: android, google-maps, google-play-services

Is there any issue with Google play services updates these days ?? 
I was developing a simple Google map application and which i was tried was to load the basic map view through my SONY U device which is running on ice cream sandwich.
There was an unexpected error saying "dialog box appear in the app and say you need to update the Google play service...etc"
 when click on it it automatically directs to Google play services in google play store.

I wanna figure this out.. Pleas help me guys...

Comment: This should help you understand things a bit: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19733649/app-wont-run-unless-you-update-google-play-services-with-google-maps-api/19734573#19734573

Comment: uninstall and install recent version of google play

Comment: I have uninstalled the recent version and re installed but didnt helped

Answer (score -2):

First go to SETTINGS

Then APP MANAGER

Find GOOGLE PLAY STORE and open it

Youll then see CLEAR DATA click that

Once you've cleared it out exit and go back to your "home page"

Reopen GOOGLE PLAY STORE

And open MY APPS click the top left of your screen a menu will pop up

Go to the ALL tab at the top 
    This will show every app, game ect you've ever downloaded. You want to go through and delete everything you dont play or use anymore. Dont worry it wont let you delete anything that came with the phone. You can delete multiple apps at once if you hold it down til it turn blue. Once you've selected all apps you want to get rid of. At the top it will say how many apps you selected and next to that it has an X click on that and it will delete all the apps you selected.