# Google Maps v2 after not works updating SDK

Tags: android, google-maps, google-play-services

I need a help. I updated sdk in eclipse and I cant use Google Maps. It shows `AlertDialog` and ask me to update my Google Play Service, but i have old device and  I think it can not be upgraded to the latest version.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>        
<resources>  
    <integer name="google_play_services_version">4030500</integer>  
</resources>
```

this is from Google Play Services lib manifest !

I really don't understand what I have to do.

EDIT!
Solution is to use google_play_service_froyo.

Comment: install google play service for froyo from the android sdk manager.

Comment: possible duplicate of [“App won't run unless you update Google Play services” with Google Maps API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19733649/app-wont-run-unless-you-update-google-play-services-with-google-maps-api)

Comment: test it in real device

Comment: if using google_play_service_froyo it works. Thanks twntee!