# Google Play Services - Update button not available

Tags: android, google-play-services

I've created a small app that uses Google Play Services. When I run the app it checks to see if the Play Services is available or not and shows an error dialog, which says "This app won't run unless you update Google Play Services". When I press "Update" it goes to the Google Play, but the Update button is not available. All I see is Open and Deactivate.

The value of @integer/google_play_services_version I use is 4030500 and the version of the installed Google Play services is 3.2.66 (845709-36)

Comment: possible duplicate of [“App won't run unless you update Google Play services” with Google Maps API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19733649/app-wont-run-unless-you-update-google-play-services-with-google-maps-api)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have had a similar problem recently (along with others by the looks of it). Google play services has been updated very recently (1st Nov I think), are you using this latest version? As by the looks of it this update has not been made available for certain regions yet on the play store. This is most likely the issue you are running into.

Comment: I tried to run the app today and it didn't show the dialog. I guess Google Play Services got updated during these two days :)

Answer (score 0):

What @user2370200 says is true, Google Play Services have been recently updated and it seems that the update hasn't arrived to all devices around the world yet. As a workaround you can use the "Google Play Services for Froyo" library. However, it is the old version. The other option will be to wait the new version on the market.

Answer (score 0):

I have Samsung Galaxy Ace (Android 2.3.6) and Nexus 10 (Android 4.2.1) for development. Yesterday I couldn't run my code for Google+ sign-in. Today however, I noticed Google Play Services update button from Nexus 10. After successful update, Google Play Services version is 4.0.31. Now my code works fine on Nexus 10. I still have the same issue on Samsung Galaxy Ace as I can't update Google Play Services from its current version 3.2.66. Hope Google Play Services update for Android 2.2 and above becomes available soon.