# google map api v2, and older version of google play services lib

Tags: android, google-maps, google-play

I am going to use maps in my android application and I should use google play services. I read lots of q\a here like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19733649/app-wont-run-unless-you-update-google-play-services-with-google-maps-api). In the mentioned question, the accepted answers suggets using older version of  google play services lib, like the one for Froyo. I downloaded google play services r10 and used it in my app, but I got errors.

If I exclude this line of code from manifest:

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

and run the app in my device (current version of google playe services in my device is 3.2.66 ), it throws error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The meta-data tag in your app's AndroidManifest.xml does not have the right value.  Expected 4030500 but found 0.  You must have the following declaration within the <application> element:     <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

and if I include it with android:value=4030500 the app runs but says that I should update my "google play services".

So what should I put android:value or Is my way correct at all ?

Regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I downloaded google play services r10 and used it in my app

The above statement is the root cause of your problems. If you really used r10 (or even r12), than after removing

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

from your AndroidManifest, you would not get this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The meta-data tag in your app's AndroidManifest.xml does not have the right value.  Expected 4030500 but found 0.  You must have the following declaration within the <application> element:     <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

This error simply says, you are linked to 4.0.30 version of the Google Play services library.

So the solution is to remove the above `meta-data` and making sure you link to one of the previous versions.

If using gradle or maven, just set your dependency version to 3.2.65. If developing the old way, download Google Play services for Froyo in Android SDK Manager, copy that from `sdk/extras/google/` into your working directory and in your project preferences choose this project as a library dependency project.

Comment: I removed the meta-data and it did not worked, also I tried "Google Play services for Froyo" and does not work

Comment: with "Google Play services for Froyo" it says The meta-data tag in your app's AndroidManifest.xml does not have the right value.  Expected 4030500 but found 0.  You must have the following declaration within the...

Comment: @persianDev You seem to be doing something wrong. Froyo version doesn't require meta-data tag at all. Start with a fresh project.

Comment: I would start with a fresh project and tell you

Answer (score 4):

I was also facing the same problem. 
After adding these two lines in my manifest file It worked .

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" 
 android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
          android:value="AIzaSyBAjfcxZvbt_COHjy7igHZnLBfsO1cfoM8" />
```

Comment: I don't know if you want to show your api key like that

Answer (score 3):

Update your google play services to the latest from your sdk manager which is rev 13

You need to add the below to manifest file

```
 <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
 android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#add_the_google_play_services_version_to_your_apps_manifest.

It's a new requirement added from the last revision 13 update to google-play-services.

Comment: I have downloaded rev 13 into my pc which I am developing with

Comment: I added and got the "app wont run ..." and in log cat I see this message: Google Play services out of date.  Requires 4030500 but found 3266134

Comment: @persianDev testing on device or emulator. the log is clear you have a older version update to new version

Comment: @persianDev check this similar to your problem workarounds suggested @ http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=61675

Comment: I have attached my device to my pc and use that for debugging the app, and I dont use the emulator.