# Google Maps Android API V2 problems with android 4.3

Tags: android, google-maps

I am novice in Google maps. Just followed this link http://www.androidhive.info/2013/08/android-working-with-google-maps-v2/
when I am launching my app, follwing error is coming up:

```
Unfotunately Googlemapsv2 has stopped
```

I have gone through lots of post on stackoverflow but still not getting where is the problem.

logcat output

```
01-14 18:05:22.301: E/AndroidRuntime(12239): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-14 18:05:22.301: E/AndroidRuntime(12239): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{example.androidhive.googlemapsv2/example.androidhive.googlemapsv2.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class fragment
01-14 18:05:22.301: E/AndroidRuntime(12239):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2343)
01-14 18:05:22.301: E/AndroidRuntime(12239):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2395)
01-14 18:05:22.301: E/AndroidRuntime(12239):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:162)
01-14 18:05:22.301: E/AndroidRuntime(12239):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1364)
01-14 18:05:22.301: E/AndroidRuntime(12239):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
01-14 18:05:22.301: E/AndroidRuntime(12239):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
01-14 18:05:22.301: E/AndroidRuntime(12239):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5371)
01-14 18:05:22.301: E/AndroidRuntime(12239):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-14 18:05:22.301: E/AndroidRuntime(12239):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
01-14 18:05:22.301: E/AndroidRuntime(12239):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
01-14 18:05:22.301: E/AndroidRuntime(12239):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
01-14 18:05:22.301: E/AndroidRuntime(12239):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-14 18:05:22.301: E/AndroidRuntime(12239): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class fragment
01-14 18:05:22.301: E/AndroidRuntime(12239):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
01-14 18:05:22.301: E/AndroidRuntime(12239):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
01-14 18:05:22.301: E/AndroidRuntime(12239):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
01-14 18:05:22.301: E/AndroidRuntime(12239):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
01-14 18:05:22.301: E/AndroidRuntime(12239):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
01-14 18:05:22.301: E/AndroidRuntime(12239):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:281)
01-14 18:05:22.301: E/AndroidRuntime(12239):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1881)
01-14 18:05:22.301: E/AndroidRuntime(12239):    at example.androidhive.googlemapsv2.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:18)
01-14 18:05:22.301: E/AndroidRuntime(12239):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5122)
01-14 18:05:22.301: E/AndroidRuntime(12239):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1081)
01-14 18:05:22.301: E/AndroidRuntime(12239):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2307)
01-14 18:05:22.301: E/AndroidRuntime(12239):    ... 11 more
01-14 18:05:22.301: E/AndroidRuntime(12239): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: API key not found.  Check that <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY" android:value="your API key"/> is in the <application> element of AndroidManifest.xml
01-14 18:05:22.301: E/AndroidRuntime(12239):    at maps.af.ay.a(Unknown Source)
01-14 18:05:22.301: E/AndroidRuntime(12239):    at maps.af.ay.a(Unknown Source)
01-14 18:05:22.301: E/AndroidRuntime(12239):    at maps.af.al.a(Unknown Source)
01-14 18:05:22.301: E/AndroidRuntime(12239):    at maps.af.be.a(Unknown Source)
01-14 18:05:22.301: E/AndroidRuntime(12239):    at maps.af.bd.a(Unknown Source)
01-14 18:05:22.301: E/AndroidRuntime(12239):    at cmj.onTransact(SourceFile:107)
01-14 18:05:22.301: E/AndroidRuntime(12239):    at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:310)
01-14 18:05:22.301: E/AndroidRuntime(12239):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.IMapFragmentDelegate$a$a.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
01-14 18:05:22.301: E/AndroidRuntime(12239):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment$a.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
01-14 18:05:22.301: E/AndroidRuntime(12239):    at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a$4.b(Unknown Source)
01-14 18:05:22.301: E/AndroidRuntime(12239):    at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.a(Unknown Source)
01-14 18:05:22.301: E/AndroidRuntime(12239):    at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
01-14 18:05:22.301: E/AndroidRuntime(12239):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
```

Manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="example.androidhive.googlemapsv2"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
       <permission
        android:name="example.androidhive.googlemapsv2.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="example.androidhive.googlemapsv2.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <!-- Required to show current location -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

   <!-- Required OpenGL ES 2.0. for Maps V2 -->
    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="example.androidhive.googlemapsv2.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
             <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

MainActivity.java

```
package example.androidhive.googlemapsv2;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity{
    private GoogleMap googleMap;
    private final String TAG ="GoogleMapsv2";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        try {
            initializeMap();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    // Function to load map. If map is not created it will create it for you

    private void initializeMap() {
        Log.d(TAG,"IntializeMap");
        if (googleMap == null) {
            googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
            // Check if map is created successfully
            if (googleMap == null) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Unable to create maps",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }


    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onResume();
        initializeMap();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Edit :
when I make following change in my manifest file

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="AIzaSyBAjfcxZvbt_COHjy7igHZnLBfsO1cfoM8" />
```

Another error comes up

```
01-14 18:28:21.323: W/Bundle(13254): Key com.google.android.gms.version expected Integer but value was a java.lang.String.  The default value 0 was returned.
01-14 18:28:21.355: W/Bundle(13254): Attempt to cast generated internal exception:
01-14 18:28:21.355: W/Bundle(13254): java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
01-14 18:28:21.355: W/Bundle(13254):    at android.os.Bundle.getInt(Bundle.java:945)
01-14 18:28:21.355: W/Bundle(13254):    at android.os.Bundle.getInt(Bundle.java:927)
01-14 18:28:21.355: W/Bundle(13254):    at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.n(Unknown Source)
01-14 18:28:21.355: W/Bundle(13254):    at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(Unknown Source)
01-14 18:28:21.355: W/Bundle(13254):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.q.v(Unknown Source)
01-14 18:28:21.355: W/Bundle(13254):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.q.u(Unknown Source)
01-14 18:28:21.355: W/Bundle(13254):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapsInitializer.initialize(Unknown Source)
01-14 18:28:21.355: W/Bundle(13254):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment$b.cE(Unknown Source)
01-14 18:28:21.355: W/Bundle(13254):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment$b.a(Unknown Source)
01-14 18:28:21.355: W/Bundle(13254):    at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.a(Unknown Source)
01-14 18:28:21.355: W/Bundle(13254):    at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.onInflate(Unknown Source)
01-14 18:28:21.355: W/Bundle(13254):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment.onInflate(Unknown Source)
01-14 18:28:21.355: W/Bundle(13254):    at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4734)
01-14 18:28:21.355: W/Bundle(13254):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:680)
01-14 18:28:21.355: W/Bundle(13254):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
01-14 18:28:21.355: W/Bundle(13254):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
01-14 18:28:21.355: W/Bundle(13254):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
01-14 18:28:21.355: W/Bundle(13254):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
01-14 18:28:21.355: W/Bundle(13254):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:281)
01-14 18:28:21.355: W/Bundle(13254):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1881)
01-14 18:28:21.355: W/Bundle(13254):    at example.androidhive.googlemapsv2.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:18)
01-14 18:28:21.355: W/Bundle(13254):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5122)
01-14 18:28:21.355: W/Bundle(13254):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1081)
01-14 18:28:21.355: W/Bundle(13254):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2307)
01-14 18:28:21.355: W/Bundle(13254):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2395)
01-14 18:28:21.355: W/Bundle(13254):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:162)
01-14 18:28:21.355: W/Bundle(13254):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1364)
01-14 18:28:21.355: W/Bundle(13254):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
01-14 18:28:21.355: W/Bundle(13254):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
01-14 18:28:21.355: W/Bundle(13254):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5371)
01-14 18:28:21.355: W/Bundle(13254):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-14 18:28:21.355: W/Bundle(13254):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
01-14 18:28:21.355: W/Bundle(13254):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
01-14 18:28:21.355: W/Bundle(13254):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
01-14 18:28:21.355: W/Bundle(13254):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-14 18:28:21.374: D/AndroidRuntime(13254): Shutting down VM
01-14 18:28:21.374: W/dalvikvm(13254): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x414929a8)
01-14 18:28:21.378: E/AndroidRuntime(13254): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-14 18:28:21.378: E/AndroidRuntime(13254): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{example.androidhive.googlemapsv2/example.androidhive.googlemapsv2.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class fragment
01-14 18:28:21.378: E/AndroidRuntime(13254):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2343)
01-14 18:28:21.378: E/AndroidRuntime(13254):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2395)
01-14 18:28:21.378: E/AndroidRuntime(13254):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:162)
01-14 18:28:21.378: E/AndroidRuntime(13254):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1364)
01-14 18:28:21.378: E/AndroidRuntime(13254):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
01-14 18:28:21.378: E/AndroidRuntime(13254):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
01-14 18:28:21.378: E/AndroidRuntime(13254):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5371)
01-14 18:28:21.378: E/AndroidRuntime(13254):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-14 18:28:21.378: E/AndroidRuntime(13254):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
01-14 18:28:21.378: E/AndroidRuntime(13254):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
01-14 18:28:21.378: E/AndroidRuntime(13254):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
01-14 18:28:21.378: E/AndroidRuntime(13254):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-14 18:28:21.378: E/AndroidRuntime(13254): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class fragment
01-14 18:28:21.378: E/AndroidRuntime(13254):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
01-14 18:28:21.378: E/AndroidRuntime(13254):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
01-14 18:28:21.378: E/AndroidRuntime(13254):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
01-14 18:28:21.378: E/AndroidRuntime(13254):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
01-14 18:28:21.378: E/AndroidRuntime(13254):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
01-14 18:28:21.378: E/AndroidRuntime(13254):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:281)
01-14 18:28:21.378: E/AndroidRuntime(13254):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1881)
01-14 18:28:21.378: E/AndroidRuntime(13254):    at example.androidhive.googlemapsv2.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:18)
01-14 18:28:21.378: E/AndroidRuntime(13254):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5122)
01-14 18:28:21.378: E/AndroidRuntime(13254):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1081)
01-14 18:28:21.378: E/AndroidRuntime(13254):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2307)
01-14 18:28:21.378: E/AndroidRuntime(13254):    ... 11 more
01-14 18:28:21.378: E/AndroidRuntime(13254): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The meta-data tag in your app's AndroidManifest.xml does not have the right value.  Expected 4030500 but found 0.  You must have the following declaration within the <application> element:     <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

Please help me to find out the solution.

Answer (score 2):

As you commented on @gokhan answer, you should do

```
<meta-data 
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

However, you still need to do

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
    android:value="@string/app_key" />
```

where `app_key` is your `Key`.

I suggest you to create an `ids.xml` file inside your `values` folder and have something like:

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_id" translatable="false">1234567890</string>
    <string name="app_key" translatable="false">QWERTTYruyfgREYT</string>
    <string name="facebookAppId" translatable="false"></string>
```

Comment: ya Gian I changed the same thing it worked .. I was trying from past so many hours ..

Comment: @ZohraKhan Your welcome. If it helped you solve your problem, then you should accept the answer to help others with the same problem find the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Probably You forgot to add your google_api_key you must add your key for use this service

You should add your key too AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application>

<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="xxxxxxxxxx" />

</application>
```

like this.

I hope this is help you

Comment: Thanks for your response. After making this change another error come up.

Comment: Based on some post in stack overflow I changed my meta data to this <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

Comment: i think you should change "com.google.android.gms.version" to "com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to download google play services r10  or even r12. Then you don't need

```
<meta-data
android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

For better understanding follow this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20019118/google-map-api-v2-and-older-version-of-google-play-services-lib)

Answer (score 0):

After adding these two lines in my manifest file It worked .

**For eclipse add this :**

```
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" 
     android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
              android:value="Your KEY" />
```

**If you are using Android Studio with gradle0.7+ then add this line:**

```
<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="Your Key" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.synergyifs.libapp;

import android.Manifest;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.ContextWrapper;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GoogleApiAvailability;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.Place;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.ui.PlacePicker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdate;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.synergyifs.libapp.adapter.PlacesAutoCompleteAdapter;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

/**
 * Created by Admin34 on 23-03-2016.
 */
public class MapDemoActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback,
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
        GoogleMap.OnMarkerDragListener, GoogleMap.OnMapLongClickListener {

    int PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST = 1;
    private GoogleMap map;
    private LatLng synergyIFS = new LatLng(18.511478, 73.801217);
    private GoogleApiClient googleApiClient;
    private double longitude;
    private double latitude;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.map_activity);

        SupportMapFragment fragment = (SupportMapFragment) this.getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.main_map);
        fragment.getMapAsync(this);
        googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(MapDemoActivity.this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API).build();
    }

    private void initMap(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        map = googleMap;
        CameraUpdate center = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(synergyIFS);
        CameraUpdate zoom = CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(10f);
        map.moveCamera(center);
        map.animateCamera(zoom);
        map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
        getCurrentLocation();
        map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        map.setOnMapLongClickListener(this);
        map.setOnMarkerDragListener(this);

    }

    private void getCurrentLocation() {
        Location location = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(googleApiClient);
        if (location != null) {
            //Getting longitude and latitude
            longitude = location.getLongitude();
            latitude = location.getLatitude();

            //moving the map to location
            moveMap();
        }
    }

    private void moveMap() {
        String msg = latitude + ", " + longitude;

        //Creating a LatLng Object to store Coordinates
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);

        //Adding marker to map
        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(latLng) //setting position
                .draggable(true) //Making the marker draggable
                .title("Current Location")); //Adding a title

        //Moving the camera
        map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));

        //Animating the camera
        map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15));

        //Displaying current coordinates in toast
        Toast.makeText(this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }


    protected void onStart() {
        googleApiClient.connect();
        super.onStart();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        googleApiClient.disconnect();
        super.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        initMap(googleMap);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        getCurrentLocation();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onMarkerDragStart(Marker marker) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onMarkerDrag(Marker marker) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onMarkerDragEnd(Marker marker) {
        latitude = marker.getPosition().latitude;
        longitude = marker.getPosition().longitude;

        //Moving the map
        moveMap();
        new ReverserGeoCoding(MapDemoActivity.this).execute(marker.getPosition());
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapLongClick(LatLng latLng) {
        map.clear();

        //Adding a new marker to the current pressed position
        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(latLng)
                .draggable(true));
    }

    class ReverserGeoCoding extends AsyncTask<LatLng,Void,String>
    {
        Context mContext;

        public ReverserGeoCoding(Context context){
            super();
            mContext = context;
        }
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(LatLng... params) {

            Geocoder geocoder=new Geocoder(mContext);
            double Lat=params[0].latitude;
            double  Long=params[0].longitude;

            List<Address> addresses = null;
            String addressText="";

           try
           {
               addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(Lat, Long,2);
           }catch (Exception e)
           {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
            if(addresses != null && addresses.size() > 0 ){
                Address address = addresses.get(0);

                addressText = String.format("%s, %s, %s",
                        address.getMaxAddressLineIndex() > 0 ? address.getAddressLine(0) : "",
                        address.getLocality(),
                        address.getCountryName());
            }
            return addressText;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {

               if(s!=null)
               {
                   Toast.makeText(mContext,s,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               }
            else
               {
                   Toast.makeText(mContext,"no address found",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               }
        }
    }
}

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest
    package="com.synergyifs.libapp"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true"/>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:name=".app.MyApplication"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity android:name=".SplashScreen">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".HomeActivity"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Login"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".RegisterUser"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MapDemoActivity"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".PlacesActivity"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        </activity>
        <!-- ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to add Google Play services to your project for
             App Indexing.  See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information. -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_api_key"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```