# google maps V2 IllegalStateException

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2, google-play-services

I have this very weird bug that my app crashes in the minute I launch it.
the call stack is:

```
01-25 15:10:52.264: E/AndroidRuntime(13707): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.out.goout/com.out.goout.Splash}: java.lang.IllegalStateException:The meta-data tag in your app's AndroidManifest.xml does not have the right value. Expected 4030500 but found 4132500. You must have the following declaration within the <application> element: <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

the thing is that I do have the tag that explained in the stack trace and the version of my google play services is 14

the code in my manifest is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.my package"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="10"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.out.goout.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.out.goout.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" >
    </permission>

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <application
        android:name="com.out.App"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="false"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar" >

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <uses-library
            android:name="com.google.android.maps"
            android:required="true" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="my key" />

        <activity
             ...
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
             ...
        </activity>
        <activity
             ...
        </activity>
        <activity
             ...
        </activity>
        <activity
             ...
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

your help is much needed

Comment: Check this link this answers your question.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21120970/google-maps-android-api-v2-problems-with-android-4-3. if you have any doubts, please comment.

Comment: not helping me.
people in these threads forgot to add the meta-data tag under the application tag. I didn't my problem is the number of version stored in that "@integer/google_play_services_version" value.
how do i need to update it?

Comment: Have you added SHA1 key in manifest <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
              android:value="Your KEY" />. One more thing Is your google maps  library is updated to latest version check sdk/extreas/google/ google_play_services

Comment: yes I did I started building my app with rev 13 of google play services and after I updated it to 14 I got the error message about the version

Comment: ok.. please post application manifest file full, xml and activity code.

Comment: Clean your build and rebuild. ./gradlew clean && ./gradlew build

Comment: I edited the thread. hope it will help

Comment: I cleaned the app several time and it didn't help

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line from manifest:

```
<uses-library
            android:name="com.google.android.maps"
            android:required="true" />
```

Comment: still the same error? SHA1 key is tightly coupled with your package name. While generating SHA1 key have you given the same package name?

Comment: yes. as I commented the bug started since I updated the the google play services from13 to 14

Comment: Which IDE are you using Android Studio or eclipse?

Comment: I am using eclipse IDE

Comment: In eclipse, remove your old library and try to re- add google play services library

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46078/discussion-between-zohra-khan-and-shalom-melamed)

Answer (score 0):

finnaly I got this...
I started a new android project and replace the android-support-v4.jar file clean the project and it helped!
Thanks a lot Zohra Khan for your help