# No GApps in Genymotion 2.0.1?

Tags: genymotion

I just updated to the new version of Genymotion, but I encountered two problems.

1. My old VMs no longer work
2. None of the new VM images have Google Apps now. None, not a single one.

So my question is, is there any way of installing GApps without a Custom Recovery?(since Genymotion gives no access to such a function as far as I know)

I'm going to email Genymotion about why they removed GApps from the images, but I suspect that they did this on purpose, so I'd like to have an alternative in case they no longer provide GApps.

**UPDATE:** After I saw people complaining about the removal of ARM support as well as the GApps, I decided to take the initiative and make a guide to fix both situations, I posted it on XDA if anyone's interested.

[[GUIDE] Genymotion | Installing ARM Translation and GApps - XDA-Developers](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2528952)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you install Google frameworks (Play, Accounts, etc.) on a Genymotion virtual device?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17831990/how-do-you-install-google-frameworks-play-accounts-etc-on-a-genymotion-virt)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Genymotion removed Google Apps from the latest version, they are in talks with Google to put them back in. For now follow the workaround https://stackoverflow.com/a/19960729/1254930

Answer (score -1):

Google does not allow to bundle them, but you can just download gapps.zip and drag over the virtual machine once running.

If the zip is flashable in clockworkmod recovery style will prompt you to install it at the very moment; if it's not flashable will just copy it to /sdcard/Download

Comment: I already figured this out a while ago. I also managed to get ARM support back. Check out the link in my Question