# How to add Google Apps to Genymotion 1.3

Tags: android, android-emulator, virtual-machine, genymotion

I am trying to use Genymotion 1.3 and some previously installed virtual devices(since now it's no longer possible to install a virtual device with Google Apps directly from their list) but i am not so sure it should be that easy...

What i have tried is simply copying the ova files into the `C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Genymobile\Genymotion\ova` folder not really working...

Updating to **Genymotion 2.0** didn't fix my problem as i am not able to start any virtual device, not even one without Google Apps... (probably due to my computer's performances)

Comment: There is an answer in this link. Please follow the steps.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17831990/how-do-you-install-google-frameworks-play-accounts-etc-on-a-genymotion-virtu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Genymotion tablet version emulator doesn't provide any google apps, only Galaxy Nexus-4.2.2 with google apps-Api 17 -720x1280 comes with google app support. So in the tablet version need to install google apps. For this purpose I simply followed these steps.

For example consider installing google app on 10.1 Tablet 4.2.2 API 17 1280x800

1.Upgrade your genymotion to 2.0.1

2.Upgrade your VirtualBox to 4.2

3.Download the two zip files from the link ARM Translation Installer v1.1 - http://goo.gl/JBQmPa and Google Apps for Android 4.2 - http://goo.im/gapps/gapps-jb-20130812-signed.zip

4.Then please copy these files to desktop

5.Open genymotion emulator and go to home screen then from the desktop drag and drop the first file Genymotion-ARM-Translation_v1.1.zip .A dialog will appear ans show as file transfer in progress ,then another dialog will appear and ask that do you want to flash it on the emulator then click OK after this it will ask to reboot the device then restart adb .

6.After this drag and drop the second file gapps-jb-20130812-signed.zip and repeat the same steps as above. restart adb and this will install google apps on your emulator.

In my case these steps resolved my issues...
Remember you can drag and drop files in to the emulator only from the desktop in case of ubuntu .

You can add any app for testing to your dropbox or any other file hosting website on your computer. Then open genymotion and go to the browser in genymotion. Go to the file hosting website where you added the app and download it from there. It would appear in the notification bar once downloaded. Click it to install it.