# Emulator manual location doesn't work with Google Play Services

Tags: android

I used to work with the "old school" location services and I could insert manual locations to the emulator.
Now that I switched to work with Google Play servcies it seems that I can't receive any manual location.
I am asking for updates:
locationclient.requestLocationUpdates(locationrequest,this);
and after inserting manual locations, onLocationChanged() is never called.

I tried to change the accuracy but still not working.
My emulator supports version 4.3 with updated Google services installed.

Note that my location code is working well with real devices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a suggestion, Try to use Genymotions for testing maps/places app.
it is faster than emulator and you can build and check maps application.

www.genymotion.com/‎

Comment: I tried Genymotions and installed the Google Play services according to this guide: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17831990/how-do-you-install-google-frameworks-play-accounts-etc-on-a-genymotion-virtu/20013322#20013322. But unfortuanetly when checking GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this), I receive '2' instead of SUCCESS.

Comment: Try to update the google apps and google play services in genymotions.

Comment: I think it is up to date. How can I verify that?

Comment: Just go apps in setting..if updates is installed then uninstall it, it will be automatically updated.. otherwise..i will send u the virtual machine with preloaded google apps.