# Android Google Maps Development with Emulator - Repository of Standard APKs

Tags: android, eclipse, google-maps, android-emulator, apk

I am a newbie to Android programming and i started putting together an application using Google Maps using **Eclipse with KitKat SDK**. I developed a simple app to display Google Maps in the **Emulator** by installing com.android.vending(4.6.16) and com.google.android.gms(4.3.25) apks. I downloaded these APKs from different sites(not sure how authentic they are).

I am making use of the command *aapt dump badging  to determine the version.*

The map opens but i was repeatedly getting a message that "*Unfortunately Play Services has stopped*"

**Objective is to ensure that I am using the right set of APKs with the emulator**

The trouble that i am facing is there seems to be no clear directives on where i can find the authentic version of these APKs. I tried Google Play and when i give a search for com.google.android.gms, it yields a result of applications. I was expecting a URL to download the recent version of the APK. Correct me if i am wrong

**1. How to download just the recent version of APKs from Google Play ? Am i looking at the correct site**

**2. Second is there any authorized site from where i can download these APKs?**

I was looking for a listing of the APKs with the version number against it. So that i can download the version that i need. I am not sure of the dependencies of the APKs on the Android platform.

**3. Finally is there any dependency between com.google.android.gms.apk and the com.android.vending.apk on the basis of the version or the SDK platform used?**

Thanks

Govindarajan

Answer (score 0):

I have a suggestion, Try to use Genymotions for testing maps/places app. it is faster than emulator and you can build and check maps application.

www.genymotion.com/‎

[LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20510695/emulator-manual-location-doesnt-work-with-google-play-services/20510958#20510958)