# Genymotion 2 - No Connection on Google Play Store

Tags: android, genymotion

I'm using Genymotion 2.0.3 and following [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20013322/2408961) to install Google Play Services for a Galaxy Nexus 4.1.1 API 16 device.

When launching Play Store I get "No Connection".
However, I am able to browse etc. So there is definitely a working internet connection.

I tried two different Google accounts just to check and also tried all three Google Apps downloads (4.1 version does not flash) all with the same result.

I have an old 1.x virtual device from the previous version of Genymotion (4.1.1 with Google Apps) and Google Apps works perfectly there.

Anyone have any suggestions on how to get Google Apps working for Genymotion 2.0.x and a 4.1.1 device?

Comment: 4.2.2 API 17 device works fine. I also tried using this version of Google Apps: http://goo.im/gapps/gapps-jb-20121011-signed.zip

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You probably installed incompatible app services. Please download correct version compatible with your API from [here](http://wiki.rootzwiki.com/Google_Apps#Universal_Packages_2). I had similar issue when I had API18, but downloaded services for API17.

Comment: Thanks. I mentioned in my comment that I did try the only version compatible with 4.1.x (20121130) with no luck. I'll try a few other versions like you suggest and see what happens...

Comment: It's been a while but I tried getting this working again. This version of GApps actually worked for 4.1.1: http://goo.gl/yc6Iyf.

Answer (score 1):

You have to download the exact version of gapps to match the device API that you wish to run on. By default Genymotion does not come with gapps. To download gapps click on any of the link below. You can only drag and drop the setup on to Genymotion if it is signed already. So please download the signed gapps.

[http://www.androidfilehost.com/](http://www.androidfilehost.com/gapps)

[http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Google_Apps)

[http://goo.im/](http://goo.im/http://goo.im/gapps)

Answer (score 0):

in GenyMotion, download the device with gapps prebuilt.

Comment: Genymotion 2.x does not have devices preconfigured with Google Apps. See the reference guide.