# How to install Chrome browser on Android in Genymotion?

Tags: android, google-chrome, apk, virtualbox, genymotion

I have a problem with installing Chrome browser on guest Android in Genymotion.

I've tried to do this (http://blog.zeezonline.com/2013/11/install-google-play-on-genymotion-2-0/) and Google services has installed, but there are a lot of troubles and apps work very unstable.

I've also tried to install Chrome directly from *.apk file and it has installed but unable to work.

Comment: which device you have ?

Comment: I've tried a lot of. Now I have Nexus 4 - 4.3 - API 18.

Comment: Maybe stability depends on my hardware?

Comment: I've resolved my problem by adding an old device image with pre-installed Play store...

http://www.learn2crack.com/2013/12/install-use-google-play-store-genymotion.html

Comment: No... there are a lot of artifacts like screen blinking and white screen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Install Google Play First with this:

[How do you install Google frameworks (Play, Accounts, etc.) on a Genymotion virtual device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17831990/how-do-you-install-google-frameworks-play-accounts-etc-on-a-genymotion-virt)

Then use Google Play just like in a real android device :)

Comment: It is impossible to install Google "frameworks" on Genymotion emulator. It does not work. It is recurring issue here on SO.

Comment: That answer was updated in May 2017, and it no longer works, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

You can install it from Google Play, but when I started, it killed my virtual device. But try Firefox. It's not Chrome, but it works like a charm. ;)