# Installing google apps on genymotion

Tags: android, genymotion

i have been following this thread [How to install Google Play Services in a Genymotion VM (with no drag and drop support)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20121883/how-to-install-google-play-service-in-the-genymotion-ubuntu-13-04-currently-i) but when i dragged and dropped these files after showing file transfer in progress it is simply copying these files to my genymotion mobile memory card. Its not asking to flash it. 
Please help me how can i install google apps on my genymotion emulator

Comment: Did you ever got it resolved?

Comment: yes, i resolved this issue

Answer (score 31, accepted):

1. Download https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_7IFWOq37FaUTVUc3FzX01Palk/edit
2. Import this into Virtual Box (just open the .ova file)
3. Open Genymotion
4. Play the device
5. Enjoy!

Comment: I double clicked it, it said-  Failed to create the VirtualBox COM object.
The application will now terminate. Details-
Callee RC: 
CO_E_SERVER_EXEC_FAILURE (0x80080005)

Comment: There is no Import Option in  Genymotion Virtual Box! can you explain bit more..  where i have to place that .ova file?

Comment: is it used for linux system as well ?

Comment: This is android 4.1.1.  What about Lollipop?

Comment: @LOG_TAG and @richa, I had to open Virtual Box first, but then I was able to double click the `.ova` and open it in Virtual Box

Comment: Works flawlessly if you wanna test pre-Lollipop versions in Genymotion.  Thanks!

Answer (score 16):

As of **Genymotion v2.0**, Geny has removed support for **ARM**, so there is no drag/n/drop support for the GApps packages. However, there is a flashable package available to let you flash GApps packages.

1. Download the following ZIP: http://filetrip.net/dl?4SUOrdcMRv, and also download the GApps package, correspondent to your emulator's Android version. You can find 1.6 - 4.3.x GApps here: http://wiki.rootzwiki.com/Google_Apps. 4.4.x GApps are here: www.androidfilehost.com/?fid=23311191640114013.
2. Next Open your Genymotion VM and go to the Homescreen.
3. Now Drag&Drop the **Genymotion-ARM-Translation.zip** onto the Genymotion VM window.
4. It should say "`File transfer in progress`", once it asks you to flash it click '`OK`'
5. Now Reboot your VM using ADB or an app like ROM Toolbox. If nescessary you can simply close the VM window, but I don't recommend it.
6. Once you're on the Homescreen again Drag&Drop the gapps-jb-20130813-signed.zip(or whatever version you got) onto your VM, and click '`OK`' when asked.
7. Once it finishes, again Reboot your VM and open the Google Play Store.
8. Sign in using your Google account.
9. Once in the Store go to the 'My Apps' menu and let everything update(fixes a lot of issues), also try updating `Google Play Services` directly.
10. Now try searching for 'Netflix' and 'Google Drive'.
11. If both apps show up in the results and you're able to Download/Install them, then congrats you now have ARM support and Google Play fully setup!

Adapted from forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2528952

Comment: Thanks a lot Lyric Wulf

Comment: It doesn't ask to flash in step 4. It says that it has copies to Downloads.

Comment: For WIN10 genymotion 2.6.0  It doesn't work drag&drop of zip file on  VM window. It is possible to enable this drag&drop?

Answer (score 2):

This Question has already been answered.[How to install apps on Genymotion Emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17831990/how-do-you-install-google-frameworks-play-accounts-etc-on-a-genymotion-virtu)

or If you find it Difficult then try solving or simply use [BlueStacks App Player](http://www.bluestacks.com/)

Comment: i have seen that link, in that link they have mentioned that it will ask for flash it but it is not asking to flash..

Comment: Great job... Its work for me

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that your virtual machine isn't compatible with your Genymotion version; try deleting and redownloading the VM.

Answer (score -2):

Most likely happened due to corrupted downloads. I have this problem and downloaded from one of the mirrors and found that they are of severely different file size. After that, all worked well and prompted me to flash it.