# Android App deployed on Genymotion - Not logging in

Tags: android, genymotion

I am trying to test my app on genymotion and am using parse as a backend.
Whenever I try to login, android displays an error: Unfortunately, the app has stopped working.

The same happens with virtualbox.

However, if I use the emulator, it works and login also works on Kindle fire jelly bean.

Any ideas on what could be wrong?

PS - If I use the internet, it works on both virtual box and genymotion.

Comment: log cat. add the log cat

Comment: have you added google play to your genymotion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add the logcat to help better. If you use google play services, you must install this in your genymotion.

You can try this:

[How do you install Google frameworks (Play, Accounts, etc) on a Genymotion virtual device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17831990/how-do-you-install-google-frameworks-play-accounts-etc-on-a-genymotion-virtu)

Answer (score 0):

download Genymotion from this link https://cloud.genymotion.com/page/launchpad/download/ and register on site then login through your id and password...