# Not able to use google play store in Gennymotion

Tags: android, android-emulator, genymotion

**I am trying to run Map-API in an Emulator** 
(`PS: I don't have a device`)

---

**My research on Internet**::

1. I found lot of posts on Stackoverflow and other forms on using a fix
   to run MAP-API in android emulator
2. Then i found out none of them work anymore when i tested the
   solutions
3. Then most of developers indicated to use Genymotion, which comes
   with built in googlePlaystore
4. With lot of hurdles i installed gennymotion to my pc and configured
   with eclipse
5. What i found out was even googlePlayServices is not availabe in
   Gennymotion too ?
6. Then i again searched for how to get the google play services in
   gennymotion, not success

---

**`Snapshot of my Gennymotion(Observe that there is no googlePlay services)`**
[image]

---

**My Questions**::

- Is it possible to run google play services in gennymotion ? If
  possible how ?
- what are other alternatives to achive my goal?

Comment: Review this question.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17831990/how-do-you-install-google-frameworks-play-accounts-etc-on-a-genymotion-virtu

Comment: yes its possible.. I did it for my google maps application testing.

Comment: @Harshid .... I used the first zip that is a translator .... succussfully .....  but second image when i tried to add ..... i get the error as device got corrupted and closes ... any Ideas ?

Comment: @Pankaj .... Really ... ? when have you tried this ... this functioonality not working ! .... what steps you followed to achieve your goal

Comment: I followed the same link posted above here in comment !!

Answer (score 0):

**Que** :**Is it possible to run google play services in gennymotion ? If possible how ?**

**Ans : Yes**

Check this link here : [Install Google Play on Genymotion](http://blog.zeezonline.com/2013/11/install-google-play-on-genymotion-2-0/)

Steps :

1. Download  Google Apps zip file.
2. Start the virtual device and once it is up and running drag and drop the zip file onto the device.
3. Next you will get a file flashable dialog click ok.
4. You will continue to see the File Transfer dialog let it run. You will (may) get errors that pop up just ignore them for now. When you get a file flashed successful dialog, click ok.
5. Restart the virtual device. You may still be getting error dialogs. just click ok and carry on.
6. If the Add Google Account Screen does not come up right away go to the apps and open up Play Store this should trigger the Add a Google Account screen.  go ahead and select the option appropriate for you and sign in or create an account. During the process you still may get errors like before just ignore it and click OK.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I used the first zip that is a translator .... succussfully .....  but second image when i tried to add ..... i get the error as device got corrupted and closes .. then i am not able to run emulator also ... is zip corropted . any Ideas ?

Comment: Might be. You can refer this link : http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2528952%5d