# Genymotion 2.2.2 issues with gapps

Tags: genymotion

I have downloaded and installed Genymotion 2.2.2 (which cane with the VirtualBox) and also downloaded gapps for 4.4 but the problem i have is after successfully flashing the ARMT v1.1, all i get is an error message saying "Oops, flashing gapps encountered and error and was unable to perform." kinda message when i want to flash the gapps. Is there anyone who can help me with this issue because i'm lost here.

Comment: Answered here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17831990/how-do-you-install-google-frameworks-play-accounts-etc-on-a-genymotion-virtu

Answer (score 1):

simply you cant install wrong gapps version 4.4 in emulator for device running with 2.2.2 , it must be match

To fix that :-

1- first thing to do download "Genymotion-ARM-Translation_v1.1 "
you can download from [here](http://filetrip.net/dl?4SUOrdcMRv)  or [mirrors](http://www.4shared.com/zip/uvnRflzZ/genymotion-arm-translation_v11.html?locale=en)

2- second download proper gapps for your android version(genymotion emulator)
[this link](http://www.teamandroid.com/gapps/) contain all versions