# Android - What is the best android emulator to build maps app?

Tags: android, emulation

i have a problem to run Android on Android Emulator,i'm using Android Emulator but it too slow,i already try another emulator such Bluestack but it is same for me,too slow,then Genymotion but there is no Google Play Services on it now,any suggestion for me??

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17831990/how-do-you-install-google-frameworks-play-accounts-etc-on-a-genymotion-virt

Comment: why u r not using real device to run ur application through adb

Comment: @james i have did it, i release my app become APK and then install it on my samsung grand 2,but the maps is show blank,how i know what's wrong with it??

Comment: @shayanpourvatan is it new version of Genymotion??

Comment: @shayanpourvatan i have do that way but my Genymotion always crash,so i back to android emulator, and continue to find another best way,sadly

Comment: no its not new, you must download google play on genymotion for build your maps. if you had a problem on device you can debug your code on device, connect your device and debug your code

Comment: @shayanpourvatan what version of Genymotion did u use?? because i use the latest

Comment: I've use version 2.2.2

Comment: ok i will try it again hopefully this problem solved,thanks a lot

Comment: don't u have a device ? ...it is difficult to work with emmulators in case of maps.... there are so many issues occur .. GPS ..lat long ...accuracy ...!!!!!!!!

Comment: @maven yes sure but this app is not for release, this is just for my friend to learn again,so i must use possible emulator that needed,hehe

Answer (score 1):

Install haxm you can download externally from [HERE](https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager), see installation instruction here [HERE](https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/installation-instructions-for-intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager-windows)

once your installed create google api based emulator with intel cpu

Answer (score 0):

Genymotion is very good emulator for testing maps based applications. It supports OpenGL. You will find a lot of good features in it. It is very easy there to set the test location points.

To install Google Apps like Gmail, Google Play Service, Play Store, Map etc you have to install GApps.

http://wiki.rootzwiki.com/Google_Apps

Answer (score 0):

You can use Genymotion to run your application.Genymotion is an open source Android emulator for app testing and presentation. You can control simulated sensors like battery, GPS, accelerometer,camera etc. It is quick and powerful Android emulator.
You can download it  from [This LINK](http://www.genymotion.com/)

Answer (score 0):

i would recommend genymotion.You can install google play services and google apps in geny motion easily.You just have to install ARM Translation in genymotion.Here's link that will help you
http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2528952