# Google play services in genymotion v2.2.2

Tags: android, macos, google-play-services, genymotion

Genymotion v 2.2.2

Mac mavericks v 10.9.4

VM 4.3

I have tried to install google play services in Genymotion by this link

[How do you install Google frameworks (Play, Accounts, etc.) on a Genymotion virtual device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17831990/how-do-you-install-google-frameworks-play-accounts-etc-on-a-genymotion-virt)

While drag and drop the ARM Translation Installer v1.1  in VM, I got the message

copies the file to sdcard/downloads instead of getting "Vm want to flash the drive".

Noting happened.

Any good suggestions???

Comment: please refer to Google Play or Genymotion manuals or forums, StackOverflow is for solving specific programming questions.

Comment: Thanks rupps. I thought it was for solving problems. I don't know what you mean on programming questions.

Answer (score 0):

I found the Error. It is a small mistake. I m using safari and I have enabled open "safe" after file downloaded in general menu. It automatically extract the zip file once downloaded from the link. Each and every time I manually zip the file and drag and drop it to the VM. It didn't work.

Once I disable that mode in safari, download it again the zip files and drag and drop it to the VM it works.

Thanks!