# Test apps that need google play services in Genymotion

Tags: android, google-play-services

I have installed genymotion and trying to run helloworld app.But it is not working.

it is showing google Play services,which some of your applications rely on, is not supported by your device.please contact the manufacturer for assistance.

Please tell me how to run test app on genymotion.

[image]

Comment: Similar topic is there:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17831990/how-do-you-install-google-frameworks-play-accounts-etc-on-a-genymotion-virt

Just install additional services.

Answer (score 1):

you need to install google play services on genymotion. you can do it like this: http://www.techrepublic.com/article/pro-tip-install-google-play-services-on-android-emulator-genymotion/