# Google Maps not showing on Genymotion .. its Showing blank Screen

Tags: android, google-maps

My google api v2 map is not working its just showing blank screen.. can anybody please see my catlog and tell the problem .. Thanks in advance ..

```
This is my LogCat Output...
and i m not able to get what Error is This

1977-2036/org.example.makwanas.contactbook D/REQUEST﹕ Error processing: com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.b.d@529b4a98 not retrying


11-10 11:53:01.659    1977-1977/org.example.makwanas.contactbook W/EGL_genymotion﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
11-10 11:53:03.851    1977-1977/org.example.makwanas.contactbook I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 136 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-10 11:53:03.855    1977-2065/org.example.makwanas.contactbook D/﹕ HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb80df6c8, tid 2065
11-10 11:53:03.987    1977-2026/org.example.makwanas.contactbook D/USER_EVENTS﹕ Event: type=58, status: gl, data: |r=8|g=8|b=8|a=8|d=16|s=0|v=Google (Intel)|i=OpenGL ES-CM 1.1 (2.1.0 - Build 8.15.10.2302)|c=Android Emulator OpenGL ES Translator (Intel(R) G41 Express Chipset)|e=t|
11-10 11:53:04.027    1977-2065/org.example.makwanas.contactbook D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2484K, 19% free 12051K/14820K, paused 20ms, total 23ms
11-10 11:53:04.079    1977-2065/org.example.makwanas.contactbook D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 940K, 22% free 11897K/15084K, paused 19ms, total 20ms
11-10 11:53:14.391    1977-1977/org.example.makwanas.contactbook W/EGL_genymotion﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
11-10 11:53:15.435    1977-1977/org.example.makwanas.contactbook I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 62 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-10 11:53:19.335    1977-2036/org.example.makwanas.contactbook D/REQUEST﹕ Connection opened to:https://clients4.google.com/glm/mmap/api
11-10 11:53:19.335    1977-2036/org.example.makwanas.contactbook D/REQUEST﹕ Open Connection
11-10 11:53:19.499    1977-2036/org.example.makwanas.contactbook D/REQUEST﹕ DRD(67): 62|147
11-10 11:53:19.499    1977-2036/org.example.makwanas.contactbook D/REQUEST﹕ Close
11-10 11:53:19.499    1977-2036/org.example.makwanas.contactbook D/REQUEST﹕ Error processing: com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.b.d@52aafbd4 not retrying
11-10 11:53:19.499    1977-2036/org.example.makwanas.contactbook D/REQUEST﹕ Retrying: com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.c.au@52ac0e18
11-10 11:53:22.751    1977-1977/org.example.makwanas.contactbook I/Google Maps Android API﹕ Google Play services package version: 6188070
11-10 11:53:22.755    1977-2026/org.example.makwanas.contactbook D/USER_EVENTS﹕ Event: type=78, status: MD, data: T
11-10 11:53:22.771    1977-2026/org.example.makwanas.contactbook D/USER_EVENTS﹕ Event: type=113, status: mc, data:
11-10 11:53:22.863    1977-1977/org.example.makwanas.contactbook W/EGL_genymotion﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
11-10 11:53:23.387    1977-1977/org.example.makwanas.contactbook I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 36 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-10 11:53:23.391    1977-2070/org.example.makwanas.contactbook D/﹕ HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb8183710, tid 2070
11-10 11:53:23.535    1977-2026/org.example.makwanas.contactbook D/USER_EVENTS﹕ Event: type=58, status: gl, data: |r=8|g=8|b=8|a=8|d=16|s=0|v=Google (Intel)|i=OpenGL ES-CM 1.1 (2.1.0 - Build 8.15.10.2302)|c=Android Emulator OpenGL ES Translator (Intel(R) G41 Express Chipset)|e=t|
11-10 11:53:23.579    1977-2070/org.example.makwanas.contactbook D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1138K, 20% free 12161K/15084K, paused 23ms, total 24ms
11-10 11:53:49.499    1977-2036/org.example.makwanas.contactbook D/REQUEST﹕ Connection opened to:https://clients4.google.com/glm/mmap/api
11-10 11:53:49.499    1977-2036/org.example.makwanas.contactbook D/REQUEST﹕ Open Connection
11-10 11:53:49.655    1977-2036/org.example.makwanas.contactbook D/REQUEST﹕ DRD(68): 62|147
11-10 11:53:49.655    1977-2036/org.example.makwanas.contactbook D/REQUEST﹕ Close
11-10 11:53:49.655    1977-2036/org.example.makwanas.contactbook D/REQUEST﹕ Error processing: com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.b.d@529b4a98 not retrying
11-10 11:53:49.655    1977-2036/org.example.makwanas.contactbook D/REQUEST﹕ Retrying: com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.c.au@52ac0e18
11-10 11:54:08.507    1977-1977/org.example.makwanas.contactbook W/EGL_genymotion﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
```

Comment: yes its connected and i have also added permissions in manifest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to run on many emulators see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13691943/this-app-wont-run-unless-you-update-google-play-services-via-bazaar/13734937#13734937) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14040185/running-google-maps-v2-on-the-android-emulator)

 But you can try on this configuration:
Test with this configuration on Android SDK Tools 22.0.1. Another configuration that targets pure Android, not the Google one, should work too.

Device: Galaxy Nexus,
Target: Android 4.2.2 - API Level 17,
CPU/ABI: ARM (armeabi-v7a),
Checked: Use Host GPU
...

Open the AVD, 
Execute this in the terminal / cmd

adb -e install com.google.android.gms.apk
adb -e install com.android.vending.apk
Restart the AVD

Also as answered before, The Google maps API v2 is now installed on the latest Google system images (api:19 ARM or x86).
So your application should just work with the new images. See detailed answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13691943/this-app-wont-run-unless-you-update-google-play-services-via-bazaar).

Answer (score 1):

You should install google-play-services on your genymotion see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20013322/1823992) more details how to do it. It will take not more then 15 min.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your map android key api is enable and different or unique with other developers if you build in team (debug mode)