# How to install Gapps on a Genymotion VM

Tags: android, virtual-machine, adb, genymotion

i know this is no new topic here but none of the links i found were helpful. i tried to follow this tutorial --> [How do you install Google frameworks (Play, Accounts, etc.) on a Genymotion virtual device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17831990/how-do-you-install-google-frameworks-play-accounts-etc-on-a-genymotion-virt)

I have no problem following the instructions until 5. Now reboot your VM using ADB (adb reboot) or an app like ROM Toolbox. If nescessary you can simply close the VM window, but I don't recommend it.

Since I have no clue how to use adb, I just closed the window, restarted genymotion and then moved the gapps via drag and drop into the vm. i can the start to flash gapps but after a few seconds i get the genymotion error "failed to flash files gapps jb....".

So i guess i know have to use adb, but since this is done via console which I have almost never used in my life, can someone please explain the adb process to me? to which directory do i have to set the console, which commands do i have to use etc.? So basically every step after downloading the adb kit until gapps are installed in genymotion? I would really, really appreciate any help since I don't know what to do anymore.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

To reboot the VM using `adb`, make sure the VM is running,

1. Open the command prompt (I'm assuming you're using windows) and just type in    `adb devices`    and press enter, that should list the devices you are running (you'll only see an IP address, this step is not necessary but it gives you an idea if your VM is actually running.
2. Next you want to type    `adb remount`    and press enter.
3. After that has executed type in    `adb reboot`    and that should reboot your VM. (Congrats, you are now a console Ninja).

If this still does not work, you could follow Method 2 below:

1. Open your file explorer and extract the two zip files you downloaded in step 1 of the tutorial you referred to.
2. Create a new folder (e.g. C:\Users\Public\New Folder) in the normal way you're used to
3. Going back to the extracted folders, open each of the extracted folders and look for a "system" folder (each extracted zip archive should have one) and copy that to the new folder you created. If you're asked to merge, allow the folders to be merged (you should end up with one "system" folder in your new folder i.e. C:\Users\Public\New Folder\System)
4. Now open the command prompt (with your VM running) and type in    `adb devices`    and press enter (just to check if its being recognized, and if it is you should get an IP address)
5. Next step, type in    `adb remount`    and press enter
6. After this type in    `adb push "C:\Users\Public\New Folder\System" /System`    and press enter (remember to replace the stuff in the quotes with your folder's path, but keeping the quotes in place)
7. This may take a while but after it is done your VM should have Google Play services installed and you may open Google Play, sign in, update all apps and you should be fine (You may get a lot of error messages but just press the "OK" button and continue with what you're doing.

NB* If you download a package that lacks the system folder, just try downloading another one until you get the right one

Kind regards!