# Genymotion v2.3.1 get Google Play store

Tags: android, google-play, genymotion

I have tried this answer [How to install Google Play Services in a Genymotion VM (with no drag and drop support)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20121883/how-to-install-google-play-services-in-a-genymotion-vm-with-no-drag-and-drop-su) and this one [How do you install Google frameworks (Play, Accounts, etc.) on a Genymotion virtual device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17831990/how-do-you-install-google-frameworks-play-accounts-etc-on-a-genymotion-virt). But with he new version of genymotion it no longer works does anyone know a way with the new version of genymotion to install Google Play?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have Safari I had the same problem. You need to put the zipped file on the Emulator!

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes "ARM Translation v.1.1 " is not working.. Here is the simple solution to install Google Play.

1.Go to this link: http://www.mediafire.com/download/jdn83v1v3bregyu/Galaxy+S4++HTC+One++Xperia+Z+-+4.2.2+-+with+Google+Apps+-+API+17+-+1080x1920.zip

2.Download the file from the link and extract to get the Android virtual device with Google play store. The file will be in the name as “Galaxy S4 HTC One Xperia Z – 4.2.2 – with Google Apps – API 17 – 1080×1920″.

3.Close all your Genymotion store running in the background.

4.Copy that extracted file in to the following folder. C:\Users\'username'\AppData\Local\Genymobile\Genymotion\deployed

5.After you copy you should see this path: C:\Users\'username'\AppData\Local\Genymobile\Genymotion\deployed\Galaxy S4 HTC One Xperia Z - 4.2.2 - with Google Apps - API 17 - 1080x1920

6.Inside the “Galaxy S4 HTC One Xperia Z – 4.2.2 – with Google Apps – API 17 – 1080×1920″ folder you will see many *.vmdk and *.vbox files.

7.Now open VirtualBox and select Machine->Add and browse for the above folder and import the *.vbox file.

8.Restart genymotion. Done.

Answer (score 0):

You must install first ARM Translation in order to get Google Play Store working.

Donwload and Install ARM Translation v.1.1
and then install the Google Play Store that
you android version requires.

For example on a custom Android 4.3 Phone:

ARM Translation v.1.1
(http://www.mirrorcreator.com/files/0ZIO8PME/Genymotion-ARM-Translation_v1.1.zip_links)

Google Play Store for Android 4.3
(https://www.androidfilehost.com/?fid=23060877490000124)

I hope this work for you!