# Genymotion error: Failed to flash gapps-jb-20130813-signed.zip

Tags: android, genymotion

I want to install Google apps on my virtual device on Genymotion. When I drag the zip file I get this error: Failed to flash gapps-jb-20130813-signed.zip.

I have tried different solutions proposed by many guides (ex: [guide 1](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/pro-tip-install-google-play-services-on-android-emulator-genymotion/), [guide 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17831990/how-do-you-install-google-frameworks-play-accounts-etc-on-a-genymotion-virt)) and different zip files for different Android versions (4.1.1, 4.2.2, 4.3), but the error is the same for each of them: "Failed to flash gapps-jb-20130813-signed.zip".
Only Gmail and Google Setting are installed.

My Genymotion version is 2.3.1.

I have no idea.
Can someone help me? :(
Thanks

Comment: 1) This is not a programming question. 2) Gapps-JB goes to Android 4.1 - 4.3, Gapps-KK goes to Android 4.4. Perhaps you have a 4.4 emulator?

Comment: which version emulator are you using? And also did you first flash using Genymotion-ARM-Translation pack?