# Use Genymotion via TiShadow start up Titanium App

Tags: titanium, genymotion, tishadow

I want to use Genymotion via TiShadow start up Titanium App, but I got the following error:

```
:[ERROR] Failed to install apk on '192.168.56.101:5555
:[ERROR] Error: INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY
```

Comment: I didn't solve this problem,but I got the reason http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17831990/how-do-you-install-google-frameworks-play-accounts-etc-on-a-genymotion-virt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A better solution is to install Google Apps on your GenyMotion devices.

**step 1**: open http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2528952
and download the Google Apps For Android 4.x files.

**step 2** :Add the virtual devices which **version is same to your download files just now** on Genymotion.

**step 3** : startup your virtual device, drag the file you just downloaded into it.

finally: run the command line :

```
ti build --platform android --target device --shadow
```

problem solved!

Comment: I used `ti build --platform android --target emulator --shadow` instead of `device`.

Comment: this command ask to select ip address from list but my genymotion ip not listed there