# Google APIs: 403 on android emulator; no error on physical device

Tags: android, android-emulator, google-api

Deploying the debug version of an app on the emulator gets me a

```
com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 403 Forbidden
{
    "code": 403,
    "errors": [
            {
                    "domain": "usageLimits",
                    "message": "Access Not Configured. The API (Gmail API) is not enabled for your project. Please use the Google Developers Console to update your configuration.",
                    "reason": "accessNotConfigured",
                    "extendedHelp": "https://console.developers.google.com"
            }
            ],
       "message": "Access Not Configured. The API (Gmail API) is not enabled for your project. Please use the Google Developers Console to update your configuration."
    }
```

Deploying the same debug apk on a physical device works OK.

What could explain the difference of behavior between the physical device and the emulator with regards to the Google APIs ?

**EDIT**
This seems to be an IntelliJ 14.1 related issue. deploying from the terminal using `adb` to the emulator, fixes it. If I find out more, I will update this. Thanks for your contributions.

Comment: It must be an emulator specific problem - No Google Services, however do you have Any referer allowed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I have no reasonable explanation to offer.

Auto-deployment by IntelliJ on the emulator was leading to unpredictable results.

Deploying the debug apk to the emulator manually fixed it and subsequent automated deployment from IntelliJ worked OK.

I guess this is a problem local to my machine.

Answer (score 0):

Some emulators don't have Google frameworks installed by default. Have you tried with genymotion and this installation?
[How do you install Google frameworks (Play, Accounts, etc.) on a Genymotion virtual device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17831990/how-do-you-install-google-frameworks-play-accounts-etc-on-a-genymotion-virt)

Comment: Thanks. See my edit above. I have the Google Frameworks installed on the emulator image. Genymotion looks great, but I need SMS access and I am not willing to spend the money at this stage.