# is it possible to install apps using emulator browser ? android

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am using emulator nexus 4 with marshmallow.

when i open google play using the browser. and search for any google app, e.g : gmail. it shows that the app already installed , although that i couldn't find the app in the emulator. 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

To use this apps install Google Play on the Genymotion. Check this tutorial [How do you install Google frameworks (Play, Accounts, etc.) on a Genymotion virtual device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17831990/how-do-you-install-google-frameworks-play-accounts-etc-on-a-genymotion-virt). After you've installed google play you can now launch default google apps like mail and hangouts, etc.