# AVD Error - Update Google Play Services

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play-services

I'm trying to incorporate GCM into my Android app

I've got compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0' 
in my app level build.gradle

I've got classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.5.0' 
in my project level build.gradle

My AVD is API23, Target Google APIs. 
My Project Structure's Compile SDK version is Google APIS API 23.

From within the AVD i can see the installed Google Play services is v 8.1.85.
So I thought this might be the problem

However I can't install a new apk via 'adb install *.apk' as I'm informed INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE

I have Google Play Services, rev 28 installed in my SDK settings

I'm a beginner on Android so I'm presuming I've overlooked something fundamental!

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling before installing your new version? `adb uninstall com.your.app.package`

Answer (score 3):

Unless Google won't update the virtual devices with the new Google Play Services you have to use Genymotion with Google apps.

How to install Google apps in Genymotion: [How do you install Google frameworks (Play, Accounts, etc.) on a Genymotion virtual device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17831990/how-do-you-install-google-frameworks-play-accounts-etc-on-a-genymotion-virt)

Comment: Yeah, my Android SDK Manager says everything is up-to-date. Only way I could avoid this message was to use a Genymotion virtual device.