# Google maps does not run on emulator and asks for Google play services update

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator, google-play-services

I use: 
Android studio 1.5
Java JDK 1.7
windows 7
Intel HAXM driver

I created a default google map activity with studio and I tried to run with but I get a message to upgrade my google servies.

As I read to documentation of android studio I have to set

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'
```

on gradle in section dependencies. This was set by default.

I don't think that the problem is on my code but in emulator's configuration.
I strongly believe that the problem start from my android sdk packages but it is not possible to make any mistake. I test the same project in Linux OS that I have install android Dev environment and there is no problem at all. Google maps works.

I installed next packages
From tools:

1. Android SDK Tools
2. Android SDK platform-tools
3. Android SDK Build-tools

From Android 6.0(API 23)

1. Everything except ARM, Wear and TV packages.

From Extra:

1. Android Support Repository
2. Android Support Library
3. Google Play services
4. Google Repository
5. Google USB Driver
6. Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator(HAXM installer)

Next I create AVD from android studio:

1. I choose a device definition one from default
2. Then system image API **level 23** with ABI **x86** and target **Android 6.0 (with Google APIs)**
   **but automatically selects android 6.0 without Google APIs**

Answer (score 0):

Your problem may well be the same as mine, see [AVD Error - Update Google Play Services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33892756/avd-error-update-google-play-services?s=0|0.0000).  Sorry no solutions but perhaps you are correct that the fault lies with the current packages