# “App won't run unless you update Google Play services” with Google Maps API android studio

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-studio

I'm trying to make google maps application in android. I've installed Google Play Services in SDK manager. When I'm running that app there's error text in emulator:

> App won't run unless you update Google Play services

build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "ge.currencyexchange"
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'
}
```

I've tried change `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'` to `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.0.+'` but after debug it throws an error about theme and in AVD everything is same

What can I do?

Comment: okay . set  `minSdkVersion 15`

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya result is same..

Comment: whats your `classpath`

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya I'm pretty new at android. can you tell me where can I find that?

Comment: The message means, the Google play services installed in the emulator are too old. Try to use a newer image for the emulator.

Comment: is there any problem if use `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.8.0'`

Comment: @Henry logic says you are true

Comment: @Henry I have latest Google Play Services and my emulator is on nexus 5. I'm using API 23 on android studio. so..

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya works on 7.8.0 thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.8.0'` instead of `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'`.

Finally

```
    dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.8.0'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error states that you need to update Google Play Services **on your device**, i.e. emulator. This error is thrown when the Play Services installed on device do not match the Play Services required by your application (or not installed at all).
Open Play Market, find Google Play Services and hit `Update`. If you use Genymotion, I suggest you to read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20013322/885028) answer.

Comment: I have latest Google Play Services and my emulator is on nexus 5. I'm using API 23 on android studio. so..