# I can't install app 6.0 on genymotion

Tags: android, genymotion

I used preview `google nexus 5x 6.0.0 API 23`
I followed these steps:

1. Download all three files.
2. Create an emulator with the Nexus 5X image and start it.
3. Flash `Genymotion-ARM-Translation_v1.1.zip` and reboot.
4. Flash `gapps-L-4-21-15.zip` and reboot.
5. Sign into your Google Account.
6. Flash `benzo-gapps-M-20151011-signed-chroma-r3.zip` and reboot.

But it didn't work for me. When I flashed `gapp-L-4-21-15.zip` and after that there's no signing in page and i cannot find play store I installed.

I showed "file successfully copied to : /sdcard/Download/ " 
I didn't find genymotion configuration too.

Comment: how did you reboot the device?

Comment: just close genymotion

Comment: I resolved my problem. It's because my browser always extracts zip to folder automatically. I haven't to extract them before i flashed to genymotion.

Answer (score 1):

1) By default Genymotion doesn't allow to download anything from internet.

It gives error as `Unfortunately browser has stopped.`

[image]

2) Download manually app in your desktop and drag it in Genymotion Window.
It will automatically install the app which you drag in it.

[image: you drag in it.]

3) On your desktop if you tried to download android app from Google Playstore, then it won't download in pc, but it starts installing in your android phone,

4) search in google as an `extension .apk`, (eg. from website [apkpure.com](https://apkpure.com/app)) then that apk can be draged to Genymotion.

5) even if it doesn't installs  app then go to VirtualBox, on which Genymotion runs, and select `Settings > Network > Bridged Network`

[image: VirtualBox]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the device doesn't proper reboot between the steps. If you installed Genymotion on the default location, you can reboot the emulator as follow:

open cmd, type in:

```
cd C:\Program Files\Genymobile\Genymotion\tools
```

enter and then

```
adb reboot
```

For installing Play Store, there is a good answer on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17831990/how-do-you-install-google-frameworks-play-accounts-etc-on-a-genymotion-virt)