# unfortunately google play services has stopped in genymotion

Tags: genymotion, google-play-games

Hi friends I added google play service to genymotion emulator,I drag the zip files of gapps and also arm v1 to it but when I opening the emulator its getting unfortunately google play services has stopped and also when I am trying to add account in it showing loading.. can anyone tell me the solution for it.

Comment: Having the same issue...

Comment: @sun have u come up with in any solution?

Comment: @Alexandr any progress with solution??

Comment: I did found an answer while going through this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17831990/how-do-you-install-google-frameworks-play-accounts-etc-on-a-genymotion-virt

Comment: Follow my answer in this question. Hope it will help you. [Question link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37361790/google-play-services-unfortunately-stopped-on-genymotion)

Answer (score 0):

I faced this same issue.This issue is generally due to not following order of 
flashing Gapps appropriately.Being a beginner in  android programming.Well, I learnt following things to keep in mind while setting up google play services:

1. **Download the ARM Translation Installer v1.1** and drag and drop the zip file onto the running Genymotion emulator device. The ARM emulator is only needed for apps that trigger a

> INSTALL_FAILED_CPU_ABI_INCOMPATIBLE

error.

2. You must close and restart the emulator fully before continuing.
3. The Google Play APK package needed is specific to the Android emulator version. You must use the corresponding Google Play Service package. Otherwise, you may notice problems with Google Play not having Internet connectivity or other strange issues.
4. If you are using below listed specific versions ,sometimes files you are using get corrupted.

   ***Solution:***

**Check android version and apk link for gapps** to be flashed:

- Google Apps for Android 6.0 ([see instructions for flashing](https://z3ntu.github.io/2015/12/10/play-services-with-genymotion.html))

1) (https://www.androidfilehost.com/?fid=96042739161891406 - gapps-L-4-21-15.zip)

2) (https://www.androidfilehost.com/?fid=24052804347835438 - benzo-gapps-M-20151011-signed-chroma-r3.zip)

- Google Apps for Android 5.1
  (https://www.androidfilehost.com/?fid=96042739161891406 -
  gapps-L-4-21-15.zip)
- Google Apps for Android 5.0
  (https://www.androidfilehost.com/?fid=95784891001614559 -
  gapps-lp-20141109-signed.zip)
- Google Apps for Android 4.4.4
  (https://www.androidfilehost.com/?fid=23501681358544845 -
  gapps-kk-20140606-signed.zip)
- Google Apps for Android 4.3
  (https://www.androidfilehost.com/?fid=23060877490000124 -
  gapps-jb-20130813-signed.zip)
- Google Apps for Android 4.2
  (https://www.androidfilehost.com/?fid=2306087749000018 -
  gapps-jb-20130812-signed.zip)
- Google Apps for Android 4.1
  (https://www.androidfilehost.com/?fid=22979706399755082 -
  gapps-jb-20121011-signed.zip)

***Update or reinstall Genymotion and Virtual box :***

If you are flashing all gapps apk correctly and you are still facing this issue.

You need to check which version of genymotion and virtual box you are using .Use latest version of genymotion and VB.

***Uninstall Genymotion and Virtualbox :***

If updating or re-installation doesn't work you  need to remove old registry files hidden in your computer which are preventing you from flashing Gapps properly.Repeat steps of flashing mentioned above.

***Note:*** Don't forgot to restart genymotion after flashing files.

Hope it helps,Cheers..Happy Coding!!!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and found lots of solutions available on the internet. I followed the steps given in http://www.thecrazythinkers.com/how-to-fix-unfortunately-google-play-services-has-stopped/ and got a perfect solution.

Answer (score 0):

To setup `Google Play Service` in your **genymotion** follow my answer in this question, hope it will help you. [Question link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37361790/google-play-services-unfortunately-stopped-on-genymotion)