# Google Play services unfortunately stopped on genymotion

Tags: android, genymotion

After installing google play services on genymotion, it shows 'Unfortunatey stopped'. I restart server but it is not working.It keeps showing the error message. How to solve ?

Answer (score 7):

To setup Google play services in Genymotion

1. Download the [ARM Translation Installer v1.1](http://www14.zippyshare.com/v/44278764/file.html) and drag and drop the zip file onto the running Genymotion emulator device. After file transfer is done, click on OK on the confirmation dialog to flash it to the virtual device

[image]

2. When the flashing process is done,  you need to restart the virtual device using command line like this

`adb reboot`

But if you just close the windows directly, you may need to relaunch the device a few times before it boots up. The restart is necessary

3. Install Google play APK package that corresponds to the version of your Android emulator. This will flash zip of gapps

Android 4.4 and above
http://opengapps.org/

Android 4.3
[Google Play Services APK](https://www.androidfilehost.com/?fid=23060877490000124)

Android 4.2.x
[Google Play Services APK](https://www.androidfilehost.com/?fid=23060877490000128)

Android 4.1.x
[Google Play Services APK](https://www.androidfilehost.com/?fid=22979706399755082)

Android 4.0.x
[Google Play Services APK](https://www.androidfilehost.com/?fid=22979706399755108)

Android 2.3.3
[Google Play Services APK](https://www.androidfilehost.com/?fid=22979706399755027)

Drag and drop the downloaded file to your active virtual device to begin the flashing process as done previously.

[image]

Reboot the virtual device once again

```
adb reboot
```

After the virtual device is booted up, you will notice that Google Play services has stopped problem will keep popping up like this:

[image]

This error occurs because the installed gapps is not updated

4. Open Google play Sign in to your account and update all installed apps, including Google Play Services

   - If you can't find Google Play, try updating the Google Hangouts app to trigger an update to the Play Store.
5. Make sure to update to the latest version of Google Play Services by opening the "Play Store" app and then the "Maps" app to verify play services is running correctly.

   - Also it is recommended to use Genymotion 2.4+ as there issues with 2.3.1

**Note**: If you see errors, be sure you installed the correct package above that matches the device version in the emulator

https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Genymotion-2.0-Emulators-with-Google-Play-support

https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/how-to-install-google-services-on-genymotion/en

Comment: How do you type `adb reboot`?

Comment: You can reboot with command line but ensure the command line is started from folder where your sdk is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25739957/how-to-reboot-android-device-emulator-in-genymotion

Comment: Nice to note, that `opengapps` you need architecture not x86_64 but x86, even though genymotion is x86_64 *(I realize it's an emulator, and theoretically can even be ARM, but info about a VM doesn't show architecture)*. That said, this answer did not work for me. I have tried multiple types of `opengapps`, but this popup message keeps appearing every second one above another, and both Google Play and Hangouts just show white screen.

Comment: Okay, I don't think it's worth a separate answer since it might be a bug they didn't fix, but: `Custom Phone 7.1.0` did have the problem, with disregard whether I use built-in install button for opengapps, or follow advices on the Internet for manual installing. However when I choose `Google Nexus 4 — 4.4.4` — it did complain once about google services just after the installation. But after reboot it works fine.

Answer (score 2):

1. Install ***genymotion*** from there main site.
2. Go to this website to download ***opengapps*** [openapps-website](http://opengapps.org/)
3. Select your option to match your `android version` in your **genymotion** virtual device. If you widows user, you can select this- [openapps option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R09z9.png)
4. Drag and drop into ***genymoion*** virtual device. It will give you warning that are you want to flash this device. So press ok.
5. Restart your virtual device and done :)

Comment: Not true: Open gapps do not work on genymotion emulator, Actually I havent been able to make any google play services to work on genymotion which renders it prety much useless.

Comment: @user6694745
Hi there, i don't know why are you not able to use `open gapps` in `genymotion`. I am still using it in my pc to play `coc` :P