# Google Play Service in Genymotion is loading for a long time

Tags: android, android-emulator, google-play-services, genymotion

I'm using `Genymotion 2.7.1`, installed Google Play on virtual `Google Nexus 5` device that is using `API 23`.

Problem: `Google Play Service has stopped`

I know that I should wait and it's caused by old version of Google Play Service.

However, something is wrong; it is taking a really long time to load page in Play Store and spent more than 1 hour on this page but nothing new happened...

**Any suggestions?**

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure that you use the latest version of `Google Play Service` and update all the Google Apps that you use.

Also try to verify if you properly follow the steps in installing the Google Play Service in the Genymotion. Here is a link [tutorial](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Genymotion-2.0-Emulators-with-Google-Play-support#installing-genymotion) on how to use Genymotion with Google Play support.

For the problem that the Google Play services has stopped on Genymotion, check the solution on this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37361790/google-play-services-unfortunately-stopped-on-genymotion) to solve that problem.

And if you are not using the drag and drop support, then this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20121883/how-to-install-google-play-services-in-a-genymotion-vm-with-no-drag-and-drop-su) can help you with that.

Comment: thanks for your attention but Google Play Service is installed and it run,even with that force close message.
but the main page of Google Play Service keep loading for a long time

Comment: While I'm figuring out the causes of this loading time, try to double check the process that you do in installing GPS in Genymotion.

Comment: i used this tutorial http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20121883/how-to-install-google-play-services-in-a-genymotion-vm-with-no-drag-and-drop-su?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem (in fact I wanted to contact you if you found any answer).
This link ( https://z3ntu.github.io/2015/12/10/play-services-with-genymotion.html ) has given a slightly different method for Android 6.0. After flashing Genymotion-ARM-Translation_v1.1.zip and rebooting, you need to download and flash gapps-L-4-21-15.zip ( https://www.androidfilehost.com/?fid=96042739161891406 ) and reboot again before signing in to Google account. Then after that you need to flash Gapps(benzo-gapps-M-20151011-signed-chroma-r3.zip is given in the above link and it worked for me). I hope I'm answering your question.