# How to install Gapps for Android 6.0 in Genymotion Emulator

Tags: android, adb, virtual-machine, genymotion

Now I'm going to install Gapps include Google play service, Gmail, Gmap and so on, in Genymotion emulator v2.6.0.
I tried to follow this command [How To Add Google Apps and ARM Support to Genymotion v2.0+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17831990/how-do-you-install-google-frameworks-play-accounts-etc-on-a-genymotion-virt)

[image]

But after done until 3(drag&drop the Genymotion-ARM-Translation_v1.1.zip), it occurred an error while deploying the file.

How can I solve it?
My Genymotion device is "Samsung Galaxy S6 - 6.0.0 - API 23".

Comment: I have already installed the Gapps for "Samsung Galaxy S4-4.4.4- API 19" VM device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

all
I have solved it right now.
First this issue occurs when Android SDK tools had some problems. I had used custom Android SDK Tools in the ADB connection settings, Genymotion.

[image]

So before installing the Genymotion-ARM-Translation_v1.1.zip, ADB connection settings set as default. As you can see :

[image]

Now you can install the ARM Translation.